# How can I expose only a fragment of IList<>?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, .net-2.0

I have a class property exposing an internal IList<> through

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<>
```

How can I pass a part of this `ReadOnlyCollection<>` without copying elements into a new array (I need a live view, and the target device is short on memory)? I'm targetting Compact Framework 2.0.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try a method that returns an enumeration using yield:

```
IEnumerable<T> FilterCollection<T>( ReadOnlyCollection<T> input ) {
    foreach ( T item in input )
        if (  /* criterion is met */ )
            yield return item;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

These foreach samples are fine, though you can make them much more terse if you're using .NET 3.5 and LINQ:

```
return FullList.Where(i => IsItemInPartialList(i)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always write a class that implements IList and forwards all calls to the original list (so it doesn't have it's own copy of the data) after translating the indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use yield return to create a filtered list

```
IEnumerable<object> FilteredList()
{
    foreach( object item in FullList )
    {
        if( IsItemInPartialList( item )
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you need to filter the collection, you may want to create a class that implements IList (or IEnumerable, if that works for you) but that mucks about with the indexing and access to only return the values you want. For example

```
class EvenList: IList
{
    private IList innerList;
    public EvenList(IList innerList)
    {
         this.innerList = innerList;
    }

    public object this[int index]
    {
        get { return innerList[2*i]; }
        set { innerList[2*i] = value; }
    }
    // and similarly for the other IList methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do the filtered elements need to be accessed?  If it's through an Iterator then maybe you could write a custom iterator that skips the elements you don't want publicly visible?

If you need to provide a Collection then you might need to write your own Collection class, which just proxies to the underlying Collection, but prevents access to the elements you don't want publicly visible.

(Disclaimer: I'm not very familiar with C#, so these are general answers. There may be more specific answers to C# that work better)