# Implementing IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() in a wrapper dictionary class

Tags: c#, dictionary, interface, ienumerable

I am using a dictionary wrapper class, and I want to iterate through it using key-value pairs as seen below

```
private void LoadVariables(LogDictionary dic)
{
    foreach (var entry in dic)
    {
        _context.Variables[entry.Key] = entry.Value;
    }

}
```

but a `NotImplementedException`is thrown because I did not implement the `GetEnumerator()` method.

Here is my wrapper class:

```
public class LogDictionary: IDictionary<String, object>
{
    DynamicTableEntity _dte;
    public LogDictionary(DynamicTableEntity dte)
    {
        _dte = dte;
    }
        bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Remove(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would you implement the IEnumerator interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53967/how-would-you-implement-the-ienumerator-interface)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to need to implement a List or Dictionary internally to hold the values of your `LogDictionary`.

Without knowing what `DynamicTableEntity` is I will assume it implements `IDictionary<string,object>`.

```
public class LogDictionary: IDictionary<String, object>
{
    private IDictionary<String, object> _dte;

    public LogDictionary(DynamicTableEntity dte)
    {
        _dte = (IDictionary<String, object>)dte;
    }

    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Remove(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
    {
        return _dte.Remove(item.Key);
    }

    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _dte.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have no special logic that your wrapper needs during enumeration you just forward the calls on to the contained instance:

```
public class LogDictionary: IDictionary<String, object>
{
    DynamicTableEntity _dte;
    public LogDictionary(DynamicTableEntity dte)
    {
        _dte = dte;
    }
        bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Remove(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _dte.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should derive from Dictionary (not IDictionary) and call base, instead of throwing an exception in the method.

Comment: It cannot act as a wrapper for `DynamicTableEntity` then, so that doesn't answer the question.