# Some help understanding "yield"

Tags: c#, iterator, yield

In my everlasting quest to suck less I'm trying to understand the "yield" statement, but I keep encountering the same error.

> The body of [someMethod] cannot be an iterator block because
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List< AClass>' is not an iterator interface type.

This is the code where I got stuck:

```
foreach (XElement header in headersXml.Root.Elements()){
    yield return (ParseHeader(header));                
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Can't I use yield in an iterator? Then what's the point?
In this example it said that `List<ProductMixHeader>` is not an iterator interface type.
`ProductMixHeader` is a custom class, but I imagine `List` is an iterator interface type, no?

**--Edit--**
Thanks for all the quick answers.
I know this question isn't all that new and the same resources keep popping up.
It turned out I was thinking I could return `List<AClass>` as a return type, but since `List<T>` isn't lazy, it cannot. Changing my return type to `IEnumerable<T>` solved the problem :D

A somewhat related question (not worth opening a new thread): is it worth giving `IEnumerable<T>` as a return type if I'm sure that 99% of the cases I'm going to go .ToList() anyway? What will the performance implications be?

Comment: I like the possitive approach 'quest to suck less' ;-).

Comment: This almost identical question has a link to some good Raymond Chen stuff: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476/what-is-the-yield-keyword-used-for-in-c

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A method using *yield return* must be declared as returning one of the following two interfaces:

```
IEnumerable<SomethingAppropriate>
IEnumerator<SomethingApropriate>
```

(thanks [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) and [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) for pointing out IEnumerator)

Example:

```
public IEnumerable<AClass> YourMethod()
{
    foreach (XElement header in headersXml.Root.Elements())
    {
        yield return (ParseHeader(header));                
    }
}
```

yield is a lazy producer of data, only producing another item after the first has been retrieved, whereas returning a list will return everything in one go.

So there is a difference, and you need to declare the method correctly.

For more information, read [Jon's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317462/some-help-understanding-yield#317502), which contains some very useful links.

Comment: For the record: or IEnumerator[<T>]

Comment: It can also be declared to return IEnumerator or IEnumerator<T>.

Comment: Darn it, beaten by 7 seconds ;)

Comment: Section 10.14 of the C# Language Specification Version 4.0 specifies that the return type of an iterator must be one of the following: `IEnumerator`, `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerator<T>`, or `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 15):

It's a tricky topic. In a nutshell, it's an easy way of implementing IEnumerable and its friends. The compiler builds you a state machine, transforming parameters and local variables into instance variables in a new class. Complicated stuff.

I have a few resources on this:

- [Chapter 6 of C# in Depth](https://www.manning.com/books/c-sharp-in-depth) (free download from that page)
- [Iterators, iterator blocks and data pipelines](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter11/StreamingAndIterators.aspx) (article)
- [Iterator block implementation details](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx) (article)

Comment: Great stuff! I liked the way you explained the topic by introducing listing 6.3 in your book - that made totally clear what's the idea behind iterators and the yield statement. Thank you for sharing this!

Comment: Hi Jon, the link to chapter 6 seems to have fallen off the edge of the web, I get rerouted to [Manning Publications](https://www.manning.com/) now, do you have an alternative link?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: I've updated the link to go to the C# in Depth page, where you can download the chapter itself.

Answer (score 8):

"yield" creates an iterator block - a compiler generated class that can implement either `IEnumerable[<T>]` or `IEnumerator[<T>]`. Jon Skeet has a very good (and free) discussion of this in chapter 6 of [C# in Depth](http://manning.com/skeet/).

But basically - to use "yield" your method must return an `IEnumerable[<T>]` or `IEnumerator[<T>]`. In this case:

```
public IEnumerable<AClass> SomeMethod() {
    // ...
    foreach (XElement header in headersXml.Root.Elements()){
        yield return (ParseHeader(header));                
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It thought that List<T> implemented IEnumerable, but apparantly it doesn't.. Now does it make sence to go the extra yield mile if you have to go SomeMethod().toList() a few lines further down the road? If my understanding serves me right, it defeats the whole purpose of yield, right?

Comment: @boris - List<T> does implement IEnumerable - but that isn't to point. To create an iterator block you *must* return either the ienumerable/ienumerator interface itself. It isn't defined for anything else.

Comment: @boris - re the "defeats the whole purpose" - not at all ;-p There are a lot of uses where a streaming API (such as IEnumerable<T>) is preferable to a buffered collection (such as List<T>) - especially if you are dealing with many thousands of records (from a file or database).

Comment: But that would kill the lazyness of my method. Not?

Comment: Sorry, re-read your answer and what you're saying is you should decide depending on the situation if you want it lazy or not. This brings me to my 2ndary question: if I know that I'm going to use ToList in 90% of the time, is it still better to return IENumerable and then ToList() it later?

Comment: @boris - very little to choose between them... if you expose IEnumerable<T>, you at least have the *option* to be lazy, but in reality it probably isn't going to hurt hugely.

Answer (score 3):

List implements Ienumerable.

Here's an example that might shed some light on what you are trying to learn. I wrote this about 6 months

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace YieldReturnTest
{
    public class PrimeFinder
    {
        private Boolean isPrime(int integer)
        {
            if (0 == integer)
                return false;

            if (3 > integer)
                return true;

            for (int i = 2; i < integer; i++)
            {
                if (0 == integer % i)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public IEnumerable<int> FindPrimes()
        {
            int i;

            for (i = 1; i < 2147483647; i++)
            {
                if (isPrime(i))
                {
                    yield return i;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PrimeFinder primes = new PrimeFinder();

            foreach (int i in primes.FindPrimes())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to have a look at what `yield` actually does for you. You'll be able to see the full code of the class that the compiler generates for you when using yield, and I've found that people understand the concept much more quickly when they can see the low-level result (well, mid-level I guess).

Answer (score 2):

To understand `yield`, you need to understand when to use `IEnumerator` and `IEnumerable` (because you have to use either of them). The following examples help you to understand the difference.

First, take a look at the following class, it implements two methods - one returning `IEnumerator<int>`, one returning `IEnumerable<int>`. I'll show you that there is a big difference in usage, although the code of the 2 methods is looking similar:

```cs
// 2 iterators, one as IEnumerator, one as IEnumerable
public class Iterator
{
    public static IEnumerator<int> IterateOne(Func<int, bool> condition)
    {
        for(var i=1; condition(i); i++) { yield return i; }     
    }
    public static IEnumerable<int> IterateAll(Func<int, bool> condition)
    {
        for(var i=1; condition(i); i++) { yield return i; }     
    }
}
```

---

Now, if you're using `IterateOne` you can do the following:

```cs
    // 1. Using IEnumerator allows to get item by item
    var i=Iterator.IterateOne(x => true); // iterate endless
    // 1.a) get item by item
    i.MoveNext(); Console.WriteLine(i.Current);
    i.MoveNext(); Console.WriteLine(i.Current);
    // 1.b) loop until 100
    int j; while (i.MoveNext() && (j=i.Current)<=100) { Console.WriteLine(j); }
```

1.a) prints:

`1` 
`2`

1.b) prints:

`3`
`4`
   ...
`100`

because it continues counting right after the 1.a) statements have been executed.

You can see that you can advance item by item using `MoveNext()`.

---

In contrast, `IterateAll` allows you to use `foreach` and also **LINQ** statements for bigger comfort:

```cs
    // 2. Using IEnumerable makes looping and LINQ easier   
    var k=Iterator.IterateAll(x => x<100); // limit iterator to 100
    // 2.a) Use a foreach loop
    foreach(var x in k){ Console.WriteLine(x); } // loop
    // 2.b) LINQ: take 101..200 of endless iteration
    var lst=Iterator.IterateAll(x=>true).Skip(100).Take(100).ToList(); // LINQ: take items
    foreach(var x in lst){ Console.WriteLine(x); } // output list
```

2.a) prints:

`1`
`2`
   ...
`99`

2.b) prints:

`101`
`102`
   ...
`200`

---

**Note:** Since `IEnumerator<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` are Generics, they can be used with any type. However, for simplicity I have used `int` in my examples for type `T`.

This means, you can use one of the return types `IEnumerator<ProductMixHeader>` or `IEnumerable<ProductMixHeader>` (the custom class you have mentioned in your question).

The type `List<ProductMixHeader>` does not implement any of these interfaces, which is the reason why you can't use it that way. But **Example 2.b)** is showing how you can create a list from it.

If you're creating a list by appending `.ToList()` then the implication is, that it will create a list of all elements in memory, while an `IEnumerable` allows lazy creation of its elements - in terms of performance, it means that elements are enumerated just in time - as late as possible, but as soon as you're using `.ToList()`, then all elements are created in memory. LINQ tries to optimize performance this way behind the scenes.

**[DotNetFiddle of all examples](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JnF24U)**

Answer (score 1):

@Ian P´s answer helped me a lot to understand yield and why it is used. One (major) use case for yield is in "foreach" loops after the "in" keyword not to return a fully completed list. Instead of returning a complete list at once, in each "foreach" loop only one item (the next item) is returned. So you will gain performance with yield in such cases. 
I have rewritten @Ian P´s code for my better understanding to the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace YieldReturnTest
{
    public class PrimeFinder
    {
        private Boolean isPrime(int integer)
        {
            if (0 == integer)
                return false;

            if (3 > integer)
                return true;

            for (int i = 2; i < integer; i++)
            {
                if (0 == integer % i)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public IEnumerable<int> FindPrimesWithYield()
        {
            int i;

            for (i = 1; i < 2147483647; i++)
            {
                if (isPrime(i))
                {
                    yield return i;
                }
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<int> FindPrimesWithoutYield()
        {
            var primes = new List<int>();
            int i;
            for (i = 1; i < 2147483647; i++)
            {
                if (isPrime(i))
                {
                    primes.Add(i);
                }
            }
            return primes;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PrimeFinder primes = new PrimeFinder();

            Console.WriteLine("Finding primes until 7 with yield...very fast...");
            foreach (int i in primes.FindPrimesWithYield()) // FindPrimesWithYield DOES NOT iterate over all integers at once, it returns item by item
            {
                if (i > 7)
                {
                    break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                //Console.ReadLine();

            }

            Console.WriteLine("Finding primes until 7 without yield...be patient it will take lonkg time...");
            foreach (int i in primes.FindPrimesWithoutYield()) // FindPrimesWithoutYield DOES iterate over all integers at once, it returns the complete list of primes at once
            {
                if (i > 7)
                {
                    break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                //Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What does the method you're using this in look like? I don't think this can be used in just a loop by itself.

For example...

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetValues() {
    foreach(string value in someArray) {
        if (value.StartsWith("A")) { yield return value; }
    }
}
```