# Does C# have anything comparable to Python's list comprehensions?

Tags: c#, python, list, list-comprehension

I want to generate a list in C#. I am missing python's list comprehensions. Is there a C# way to create collections on the fly like list comprehensions or generator expressions do in python?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you are using C# 3.0 (VS2008) then LINQ to Objects can do very similar things:

```
List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>();
IEnumerable<Foo> extract = from foo in fooList where foo.Bar > 10 select Foo.Name.ToUpper();
```

Answer (score 15):

Matt has mentioned query expressions. These are available for LINQ in general, by the way - not just LINQ to Objects. (For example, the same query applied to a LINQ to SQL datacontext would execute the filter and projection on the database.)

The query expressions in C# 3 are simply syntactic sugar over writing normal C# code - although query expressions usually end up calling [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). (They don't have to, and the compiler doesn't care, but they usually do.) There are various things you can do with collections which aren't available in C# query expressions, but which are supported by method calls, so it's worth being aware of both kinds of syntax. For instance, Matt's query expression of:

```
List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>();
IEnumerable<string> extract = from foo in fooList where foo.Bar > 10 select foo.Name.ToUpper();
```

is "pre-processed" into:

```
List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>();
IEnumerable<string> extract = fooList.Where(foo => foo.Bar > 10)
                                     .Select(foo => foo.Name.ToUpper());
```

If you want to (say) filter based on the index of the value in the original collection, you can use an [appropriate overload of Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx) which is unavailable via query expressions:

```
List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>();
IEnumerable<string> extract = fooList.Where((foo, index) => foo.Bar > 10 + index)
                                     .Select(foo => foo.Name.ToUpper());
```

Or you could find the length of the longest name matching the criteria:

```
List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>();
int longestName = fooList.Where((foo, index) => foo.Bar > 10 + index)
                         .Select(foo => foo.Name)
                         .Max();
```

(You don't *have* to do the projection and max in separate methods - there's a `Max` overload which takes a projection as well.)

My point is that using extension methods you can very easily build up sophisticated queries.

You mention Python generators as well - C# has this in the form of [iterator blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317462/some-help-understanding-yield). Indeed, these are incredibly useful when implementing LINQ-like operators. (Because most of LINQ to Objects is based on extension methods, you can add your own operators which look "native" to LINQ - although you can't change the query expression syntax yourself.)

Comment: Python's list comprehension can create a list from scratch in addition to *extracting* from another list. As far as I understand, what you have shown *extracts* from an existing list. But the OP mentions *generate* and *create* in their post. I think my answer does the creating thing. Please correct me if I am wrong. After all, you only looked at the question... and the question [answered itself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9147/282546) ;-)

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ: The question isn't really clear enough, to be honest - it would have been closed if it had been raised these days. I'm not going to put any more effort into an answer on an unclear question... although I'd personally use `Enumerable.Range` to act as a "source" rather than the `for` loop in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for `Enumerable.Range` pointer. Other than that, is that C# code equivalent to the python's list comprehension? Or, is there any more elegant way in C#? Compared to python's one liner, that C# code looks bulky.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ: Well it would be `string.Join(", ", Enumerable.Range(1, 50).Select(x => $"cb{x:00}")))` which really isn't that long...

Comment: That `$` thing right there is C# 6 thing, if I am not mistaken, which has really made it a lot simpler and elegant. Thanks.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ: Well, you'd only need to change `$"cb{x:00}"` to `string.Format("cb{0:00}", x)`, so there's not *very* much difference - but yes, it's still an improvement.

Answer (score 7):

[`List<T>.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) behaves just like list comprehensions by performing the same operation on every item on an existing list and then returning a new collection.  This is an alternative to using Linq especially if you are still using .NET 2.0.

In Python, a simple list comprehension example:

```
>>> foo = [1, 2, 3]
>>> bar = [x * 2 for x in foo]
>>> bar
[2, 4, 6]
```

For C# 3.0, you can pass a lambda function specifying what type of mapping function is needed.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var foo = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3};
    var bar = foo.ConvertAll(x => x * 2);    // list comprehension

    foreach (var x in bar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);  // should print 2 4 6
    }
}
```

For C# 2.0, you can use an anonymous method with the `Converter` delegate to perform the equivalent.

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<int> foo = new List<int>(new int[]{ 1, 2, 3});
    List<int> bar = foo.ConvertAll(new Converter<int, int>(delegate(int x){ return x * 2; }));  // list comprehension

    foreach (int x in bar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);  // should print 2 4 6
    }
}
```

(Note: the same can be done with Arrays using [`Array.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is very very late an answer, but I too wondered if C# has anything equivalent to python's list comprehension. Answers from both [Matt Campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/323039/3375713) and [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/323058/3375713) show how to *extract* a list from an existing one, as far as I understood. But a python's list comprehension can also create a list from scratch. So here is what I came up with.

First I will show the python list comprehension, and then its C# equivalent that I came up with.

The toy task is to create a string like this

```
cb01, cb02, cb02, ... , cb50
```

#### Python list comprehension:

```py
s = ', '.join('cb{0:02}'.format(i+1) for i in range(50))
```

#### C# equivalent I came up with:

```
string s = String.Join(", ", new Func<List<string>>( () =>
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(1, 50))
        list.Add(String.Format("cb{0:00}", i));

    return list;
}).Invoke());
```

I am not sure if I over-did anything or not though.

---

**Edit:** (from what Jon Skeet mentioned in his comment, a real one-liner equivalent to python's list comprehension)

```
String.Join(", ", Enumerable.Range(1, 50).Select(x => $"cb{x:00}")))
```

Note that `$` thing is a [C# 6 feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879355.aspx). If you are still not using C# 6, you can go with the old `String.Format()` way.

Answer (score 1):

There's this:

```cs
new List<FooBar> { new Foo(), new Bar() }
```

which is only a little longer than its python equivalent:

```py
[Foo(), Bar()]
```

And then there is this:

```cs
public IEnumerable<FooBar> myFooBarGenerator() {
     yield return new Foo();
     yield return new Bar();
}
```

which is the python equivalent of:

```py
def myFooBarGenerator():
    yield Foo()
    yield Bar()
```