# Advice for Python programmer writing C#

Tags: c#, python

I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683273/advice-for-c-programmer-writing-python) about advice for C# programmers writing Python code but I am going the opposite direction.

What are some tips, tricks, caveats for a Python programmer writing C# code?

Comment: arent you duplicating that question in a way?  it seems symetrical..

Comment: No. This question is about how to program in C# when you are used to the Pythonic way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some examples I meant by my question:

- [`enumerate()` in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521687/c-foreach-with-index)

  another possibility:

  ```
  "abc".Where((x,i) => true).Select((x, i) => string.Format("{0}: {1}", i, x))

  0: a
  1: b
  2: c
  ```
- [list comprehension in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323032/does-c-have-anything-comparable-to-pythons-list-comprehensions/323039#323039)

  ```
  List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>();
  IEnumerable<Foo> extract = from foo in fooList where foo.Bar > 10 select Foo.Name.ToUpper();
  ```

Comment: i used to have to switch between python and C# all the time and when LINQ came out, it made me so happy to have list comprehension-ish stuff available.