# yield return works only for IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

Can I use `yield return` when the return type is an `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` or an `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Some help understanding "yield"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317462/some-help-understanding-yield)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`yield return` works for exactly 4 cases:

- `IEnumerable`
- `IEnumerable<T>`
- `IEnumerator`
- `IEnumerator<T>`

This is because it has to build a state machine internally; a dictionary (etc) wouldn't be possible with this. You can of course just `return` a suitable type instead.

Comment: Handy article here http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter6/iteratorblockimplementation.aspx if you want to implement IEnumerable yourself.

Comment: @Rory yes, implementing it yourself is a massive PITA, and I can't think of any "normal" reasons to ever do so, now that iterator blocks exist. I have a few such, but that's usually for compatibility on projects that need to build even on C# 1.2 compilers; not exactly the "normal" scenario.

Comment: Agreed, although IGrouping could be nice in some cases it seems easier to use an IEnumerable<Tuple<x,x>> instead so you get the magic of yield return.

Answer (score 16):

You could however return `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K,V>>` that would be similar to a dictionary. You would then yield return KeyValuePairs. You could even wrap this with another method that creates a dictionary out of the return. The only thing the first method would not guarantee is uniqueness in the keys.

Comment: Then you lose the O(1) access time, and have to cycle through every single KVP to find the correct key, taking at worst O(n) times.

Answer (score 5):

Answer: No. A `yield return` statement can be used only if the return type is `IEnumerator`, `IEnumerator<T>`, `IEnumerable`, or `IEnumerable<T>`.

From §8.14 of the [C# 3.0 spec](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.doc):

The yield statement is used in an iterator block (§8.2) to yield a value to the enumerator object (§10.14.4) or enumerable object (§10.14.5) of an iterator or to signal the end of the iteration.

From §10.14.4:

An enumerator object has the following characteristics:

1. It implements `IEnumerator` and `IEnumerator<T>`, where `T` is the yield type of the iterator.

[...]

From §10.14.5:

An enumerable object has the following characteristics:

1. It implements `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`, where `T` is the yield type of the iterator.

[...]

Answer (score 2):

No, because an iterator block is simply a state machine built on your behalf by the compiler.  This feature allows you to "yield" and item as a portion of a sequence.

If the return type was other than `IEnumerable<T>` (like `IDictionary` for example)  the compiler would have to generate methods to implement that interface and at that point it wouldn't make much sense because you would be working with a collection rather than a sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Just call the iterator method and chain `ToDictionary` or `GroupBy` after it, and you have much the same thing. Put that in a one-line wrapper method if you need to call it like that from several places.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. While the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) doesn't exactly spell it out, the way it is worded implies that it can only be used when the return type of the method is either `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>`. You might be able to write a class that implements `IGrouping` given an `IEnumerable` (that would be returned from your method using `yield return`), but that's about the only option really.

Comment: The language spec spells it out instead... see 8.18 in ECMA 334

Answer (score 0):

you can always create a IAsyncEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T,V>> using a repository or list and yield return new KeyValuePair<T,V>(obj1,obj2); and a second function to call the method above that returns 'IAsyncEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T,V>>'  add into a dictionary and add to the dictionary if (!dic.TryGetValue(output.Key,out object s)) assuming you want unique keys

Answer (score -1):

nope, just ienumerable :-)