# EF4.1 - recursive query to get hierarchical data

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I come up with this:

```
public partial class Forum
{
    public List<Forum> GetHierachy(Forum foru)
    {
        foreach (var forum in foru.SubForums.ToList())
        {
            yield return GetHierachy(forum);
        }
    }
}
```

For this:

```
public partial class Forum
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SubForumId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Forum> SubForums { get; set; }
    public virtual Forum ParentForum { get; set; }
}
```

And I get that:

```
The body of 'Jami.Data.Forum.GetHierachy(Jami.Data.Forum)' cannot be an iterator block because 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Jami.Data.Forum>' is not an iterator interface type:
```

Then I found out this:
[Some help understanding "yield"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317462/some-help-understanding-yield)

So I changed my method to:

```
public IEnumerable<Forum> GetHierachy(Forum foru)
    {
        foreach (var forum in foru.SubForums.ToList())
        {
            yield return GetHierachy(forum);
        }
    }
```

And Now I'm getting missing cast exception.

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Jami.Data.Forum>' to 'Jami.Data.Forum'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

A this point I have no slighest idea why this exception occurs. I might be wrong, but for me it looks like returning collection not single item.

Comment: Read [yield (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx).

Comment: Yes it returns collection because it returns return type of your `GetHierarchy`. Iterators do not nest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it returns collection because it returns return type of your `GetHierarchy`. Iterators do not nest. You need something like:

```
public IEnumerable<Forum> GetHierachy(Forum forum)
{
    yield forum;

    foreach (var x in forum.SubForums.SelectMany(s => GetHierarchy(s)))
    {
        yield return x;
    }
}
```

When I look at this query I definitely don't like it. It is ugly and it will perform terribly bad because this will use lazy loading to load data = a lot of queries to database. Hierarchical queries should be done directly in database with Common table expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this excellent solution to [query hierarchical data](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/02/28/manage-trees-with-entity-framework-part-ii/)

It may require some db alterations but its worth it.

Comment: This solution is not viable if you do not intend to tie yourself down to one implementation of database and only supports trees, what about graphs (many-to-many) hierarchy?