# How to lazy load with my own IQueryable that is backed by a list

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, iqueryable

I have a list of permissions defined like this:

```
private List<PermissionItem> permissionItems;
private ReadOnlyCollection<PermissionItem> permissionItemsReadOnly;
```

This list is retrieved from a web service via a background thread.  The read only version is filled from the List version.

I expose this list to the rest of my (rather large) application like this:

```
public IQueryable<PermissionItem> PermissionItems
{
   get
   {
       // Make sure that the permissions have returned.  
       // If they have not then we need to wait for that to happen.
       if (!doneLoadingPermissions.WaitOne(10000))
           throw new ApplicationException("Could not load permissions");

       return permissionItemsReadOnly.AsQueryable();
   }
}
```

This is all well and good.  The user can ask for permissions and get them once they have loaded.

But if I have code like this in a constructor (in a different class):

```
ThisClassInstanceOfThePermisssions = SecurityStuff.PermissionItems;
```

Then I am fairly sure that will block until the permissions return.  But it does not need to block until the permissions are actually used.

I have read that IQueryable is "Lazy Loading".  (I have used this feature in my Entity Framework code.)

**Is there a way I could change this to allow references to my IQueryable at any time, and only block when the data is actually used?**

Note: This is a "nice to have" feature.  Actually loading the permissions does not take too long.  So if this is a "roll your own" query/expression stuff, then I will probably pass.  But I am curious what it takes to make it work.

Comment: What behavior do you want for the returned IQueryable? What should happen if the list is not completely loaded?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque - I would prefer to move my `WaitOne` code to somewhere where the data in the list is actually accessed.  And allow assigning reference (and maybe creating "sub" IQueryables) to be set up without blocking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is possible. First, probably you should switch to IEnumerable as you are not using any IQueryable features. Next, you need to implement a new iterator:

```
public IEnumerable<PermissionItem> PermissionItems
{
   get
   {
        return GetPermissionItems();
   }
}
static IEnumerable<PermissionItem> GetPermissionItems()
{
       // Make sure that the permissions have returned.  
       // If they have not then we need to wait for that to happen.
       if (!doneLoadingPermissions.WaitOne(10000))
           throw new ApplicationException("Could not load permissions");

       foreach (var item in permissionItemsReadOnly) yield return item;
}
```

The event will only be waited on if the caller of the property enumerates the `IEnumerable`. Just returning it does nothing.

Comment: He says he exposes the list to the rest of the app, not over the wire. Anyway, IQueryable does not magically allow query over the wire, either.

Comment: @usr - This is what I was looking for.  Seems I never think of using the `yeild`, but it allows some good stuff!

Comment: @Vaccano, you can also implement IEnumerable manually but that is an awful task. yield and manual implementations have the same expressive power.

Comment: @Vaccano J.Skeet has got really great stuff on iterators, you can get very detailed insight on how that works. See his answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/317502/706456). Anyways +1 for a helpful answer.

Comment: As an oddity, ReSharper wants me to change the last line to `return permissionItemsReadOnly;`  Is that the same thing as using the yield?

Comment: No that would make the method execute synchronously. R# is applying a useful heuristic here, but in this case it does damage. Choose "ignore with comment" from the light bulb menu to document your intention to others!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) class.

> Lazy initialization occurs the first time the [Lazy.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642177.aspx) property
>   is accessed. Use an instance of Lazy to defer the creation of a
>   large or resource-intensive object or the execution of a
>   resource-intensive task

Comment: This requires callers to change.

Comment: I had never heard of this one.  Thanks for pointing me to it.  I think usr's answer is what I need, but I am adding this to my toolbox.