# Why cannot use iterator block with IOrderedEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, mono, iterator

I wrote this:

```
using System;using System.Linq;
static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Inspect<T> (this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("In Inspect");
        //return source;    //Works, but does nothing
        foreach(T item in source){
            Console.WriteLine(item);
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Then went to test it with this:

```
var collection = Enumerable.Range(-5, 11)
    .Select(x => new { Original = x, Square = x * x })
    .Inspect()
    .OrderBy(x => x.Square)
    //.Inspect()
    .ThenBy(x => x.Original)
    ;
foreach (var element in collection)
{
Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

The first use of `Inspect()` works fine. The second one, commented out, won't compile. The return of `OrderBy` is `IOrderedEnumerable`. I'd have thought `IOrderedEnumerable` *is-a* `IEnumerable` but, rolling with the punches, I tried:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> Inspect<T> (this IOrderedEnumerable<T> source)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("In Inspect (ordered)");
    foreach(T item in source){
        Console.WriteLine(item);
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

But this won't compile either. I get told I cannot have an iterator block because System.Linq.IOrderedEnumberable is not an iterator interface type.

What am I missing? I cannot see why people wouldn't want to iterate over an ordered collection the same way they do with the raw collection.

(Using Mono 2.10.8.1, which is effectively C# 4.0, and MonoDevelop 2.8.6.3)

**UPDATE:**

As joshgo kindly pointed out, I can take an input parameter of `IOrderedEnumerable`, it does indeed act *as-a* `IEnumerable`. But to iterate I must return `IEnumerable`, and my original error was caused by `ThenBy`, which insists on being given `IOrderedEnumerable`. Very reasonable too. But is there a way to satisfy `ThenBy` here?

**UPDATE2:**

After playing with the code in both answers (both of which were very helpful), I finally understood why I can't use yield with an IOrderedEnumerable return: there is no point, because the values have to be fully available in order to do the sort. So instead of a loop with yield in it, I may as well use a loop to print out all items, then just return source once at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe an explanation of the error can be found here: [Some help understanding "yield"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317462/some-help-understanding-yield)

Quoting Lasse V. Karlsen:

> A method using yield return must be declared as returning one of the
>   following two interfaces:  IEnumerable or IEnumerator

The issues seems to be with the `yield` operator and the return type of your second function,  `IOrderedEnumerable`.

If you change the return type from `IOrderedEnumerable` to `IEnumerable`, then the 2nd Inspect() call will no longer be an error. However, the `ThenBy()` call will now throw an error. If you temporarily comment it out, it'll compile but you do lose access to the `ThenBy()` method.

```
var collection = Enumerable.Range(-5, 11)
    .Select(x => new { Original = x, Square = x * x })
    .Inspect()
    .OrderBy(x => x.Square)
    .Inspect()
    //.ThenBy(x => x.Original)
    ;
foreach (var element in collection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

...

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Inspect<T> (this IOrderedEnumerable<T> source)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("In Inspect (ordered)");
    foreach(T item in source){
        Console.WriteLine(item);
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to answer the question at all :/

Comment: @Earlz Not at all! (Ah, I see you wrote your comment before joshgo did a major edit.)

Comment: Aha! You're right, the problem was the call to ThenBy(). In fact `IEnumerable<T> Inspect<T> (this IEnumerable<T> source)` causes no problems with `OrderBy()`. But an override cannot change by just return type; I wonder if there is a way to satisfy ThenBy?

Comment: You can revert your Inspect<T> function back to returning a IOrderedEnumerable type. Then remove the yield operator and for-loop, and just return an IOrderedEnumerable type instead. It should work, and you should have access to the ThenBy(). Let me know if you need a code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply your extension method after operation, which returns `IOrdereEnumerable` and continue ordering, then you need to create second overloaded extension:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> Inspect<T>(this IOrderedEnumerable<T> source)
{
    Console.WriteLine("In Ordered Inspect");
    // inspected items will be unordered
    Func<T, int> selector = item => { 
              Console.WriteLine(item); 
              return 0; };

    return source.CreateOrderedEnumerable(selector, null, false);    
}
```

What is interesting here:

- You need to return `IOrderedEnumerable` in order to apply `ThenBy` or `ThenByDescending`
- `IOrderedEnumerable` is not created via `yield return`. In your case it could be achieved by creating it from source
- You should create dummy selector, which does not break ordering of items
- Output will not contain ordered items, because selector is executed in same order as input sequence.

If you want to see ordered items, you need to execute your `OrderedEnumerable`. This will force executing of all operators, which present before `Inspect`:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> Inspect<T>(this IOrderedEnumerable<T> source)
{
    Console.WriteLine("In Ordered Inspect");            
    var enumerable = source.CreateOrderedEnumerable(x => 0, null, false);    
    // each time you apply Inspect all query until this operator will be executed
    foreach(var item in enumerable)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    return enumerable;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks LazyB. Very interesting. I think your second example can be simplified to: `Console.WriteLine("In Ordered Inspect"); foreach(T item in source){Console.WriteLine("Inspect(O):"+item);} return source;` (?)

Comment: @DarrenCook yes, you are right. If we do not sort anything, we can return source