# Outputting a C# Object list

Tags: c#

I have

```
List<dynamic> events = new List<dynamic>();

for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0) //is even
    {
        var dataStart = new
        {
            TimeId = startTime.AddSeconds(i),
            ValueStart = i
        };
    }
}
```

how can I output what is in the List object? I am very new to C# so I have tried

```
for (int j = 0; j < events.Count; j++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(events);
}
```

but this is not working. Any ideas as to what I need to do to correctly output the values of the object?

Comment: You didn't even add any item to your list. you just declared some anonymous types and throw them away.

Answer (score 2):

First, ***add*** created items into the *list*:

```
List<dynamic> events = new List<dynamic>();

for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
  if (i % 2 == 0) {//is even
    events.Add( // <- Do not forget Add
      new {
        TimeId = startTime.AddSeconds(i),
        ValueStart = i }
    );
```

Then print the list out

```
foreach(var item in events)
  if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, item))
    Console.WriteLine("time: {0} value: {1}", item.TimeId, item.ValueStart);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there, just need to access the element via index (assuming you have anything in the collection):

```
for (int j = 0; j < events.Count; j++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(events[j].FooProperty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to understand that you're having a `List` of dynamic type (I don't know what that is, maybe you're local Class file). It is initialized as

```
List<dynamic> events = new List<dynamic>();
```

Now, the events would have a list of elements that would be `dynamic` objects.

When you need to output it, you need to reference it. You need this to do that

```
for (int j = 0; j < events.Count; j++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(events[j].SomeProperty.ToString());
}
```

This code would get some property of each of the `dynamic` object inide the events list and then it would write it in the Console.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You forgot to add your elements to the list:

   ```
   DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
   List<dynamic> events = new List<dynamic>();
   for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
   {
       if (i % 2 == 0) //is even
       {
           var dataStart = new
           {
               TimeId = startTime.AddSeconds(i),
               ValueStart = i
           };
           events.Add(dataStart); // <-- 
        }
    }
   ```
2. Just use a `foreach` for writing to the console like this:

   ```
   foreach (var dataPoint in events)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(dataPoint);
   }
   ```

EDIT: Since I lost the race, I may as well present a more interesting way to do this:
(This also has the bonus of being backwards compatible to C# 2, whereas `dynamic` only exists from C# 4 on.)

```
public static IEnumerable<object> GetEvents(DateTime startTime)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0) //is even
        {
            yield return new
            {
                TimeId = startTime.AddSeconds(i),
                ValueStart = i
            };
        }
    }
}
```

You would call this like so:

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
foreach (var dataPoint in GetEvents(startTime))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dataPoint);
}
```

More on `yield return` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/317502/2946652) by Jon Skeet.