# Why have Enumerator struct and EnumeratorImpl class?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am looking at the [Roslyn September 2012 CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) with Reflector, and I noticed that the ChildSyntaxList struct has the following:

```
public struct ChildSyntaxList : IEnumerable<SyntaxNodeOrToken>
{
    private readonly SyntaxNode node;
    private readonly int count;

    public Enumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return node == null ? new Enumerator() : new Enumerator(node, count);
    }

    IEnumerator<SyntaxNodeOrToken> IEnumerable<SyntaxNodeOrToken>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return node == null
            ? SpecializedCollections.EmptyEnumerator<SyntaxNodeOrToken>()
            : new EnumeratorImpl(node, count);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return node == null
            ? SpecializedCollections.EmptyEnumerator<SyntaxNodeOrToken>()
            : new EnumeratorImpl(node, count);
    }

    public struct Enumerator
    {
        internal Enumerator(SyntaxNode node, int count)
        {
            /* logic */
        }

        public SyntaxNodeOrToken Current { get { /* logic */ } }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            /* logic */
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            /* logic */
        }
    }

    private class EnumeratorImpl : IEnumerator<SyntaxNodeOrToken>
    {
        private Enumerator enumerator;

        internal EnumeratorImpl(SyntaxNode node, int count)
        {
            enumerator = new Enumerator(node, count);
        }

        public SyntaxNodeOrToken Current { get { return enumerator.Current; } }

        object IEnumerator.Current { get { return enumerator.Current; } }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            return enumerator.MoveNext();
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            enumerator.Reset();
        }
    }
}
```

That is, there is a `GetEnumerator` method which returns a struct.

It looks like that

1. using a struct is a performance gain similar to the BCL [`List<T>.Enumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x854yt9s.aspx) struct, as noted [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3168435/979003), and that
2. the struct does not implement [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) so as to not have to worry about bugs that could arise from doing so, [as noted on Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/14/to-box-or-not-to-box-that-is-the-question.aspx).

However, unlike the BCL [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class, there is a nested `EnumeratorImpl` class. Is the purpose of this to

1. avoid having a disposable struct, and
2. avoid boxing within the explicitly implemented `IEnumerable<SyntaxNodeOrToken>.GetEnumerator` and `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` methods?

Are there any other reasons?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Are there any other reasons?

None come to mind. You seem to have accurately described the purposes of this rather odd implementation of the sequence pattern.

I hasten to add: Roslyn is an unusual .NET application in its complexity, in its performance requirements, and in the number of objects that it generates. A compiler that analyzes programs with thousands of files, millions of lines and tens of millions of characters *while the user is typing* has to do some pretty unusual things to ensure that it does not overwhelm the garbage collector. Roslyn therefore uses pooling strategies, uses mutable value types, and other out-of-the-mainstream practices to help achieve these performance goals. I do not recommend taking on the expense and difficulty associated with these practices *unless you have empirical evidence identifying a serious performance problem that these practices mitigate*. Just because this code was written by the C# compiler team does not mean that this is the gold standard for how you should be writing your mainstream business objects.

Comment: I agree your wouldn't do these optimizations unless they were required (as demonstrated by empirical evidence), because of their development and maintenance cost. But what if they were free? What if some code generator or compiler would do these optimizations for you, so you wouldn't have to type them nor read them? Is there any evidence that the Roslyn compiler has been written using such a code generator or rewriter, or even that the Roslyn compiler is doing these optimizations itself, on itself? Both would certainly be possible...