# What is the reason for creating IEnumerator?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

`IEnumerator` contains `MoveNext()`, `Reset()` and `Current` as its members. Now assume that I have moved these methods and property to `IEnumerable` interface and removed `GetEnumerator()` method and `IEnumerator` interface.

Now, the object of the class which implements `IEnumerable` will be able to access the methods and the property and hence can be iterated upon.

- Why was the above approach not followed and the problems I will face
  if I follow it?
- How does presence of `IEnumerator` interface solve those problems?

Comment: quick thought; it is mainly used for foreach loop - compiler stuff!!

Comment: GetEnumerator returns a new enumerator so that multiple enumerators can navigate independent through a collection. With your solution is this not possible.

Comment: @flindeberg There is no homework tag.  He isn't doing anything improperly.

Comment: @flindeberg If someone wants to explain that a problem is a homework problem they're certainly welcome to.  It's not required, and a tag is strictly an incorrect way to indicate that a question is a homework problem.

Comment: @flindeberg I thought we got over this a long time ago... homework questions shouldn't be treated any differently, especially not with a meta tag that was nuked from orbit years ago.

Answer (score 51):

An iterator contains separate state to the collection: it contains a cursor for where you are *within* the collection. As such, there has to be a separate object to represent that extra state, a way to *get* that object, and operations *on* that object - hence `IEnumerator` (and `IEnumerator<T>`), `GetEnumerator()`, and the iterator members.

Imagine if we *didn't* have the separate state, and then we wrote:

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

foreach (var x in list)
{
    foreach (var y in list)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", x, y);
    }
}
```

That *should* print "1 1", "1 2", "1 3", "2 1" etc... but without any extra state, how could it "know" the two different positions of the two loops?

Answer (score 25):

> Now assume that I have moved these methods and property to IEnumerable interface and removed GetEnumerator() method and IEnumerator interface.

Such a design would prevent concurrent enumeration at the collection. If it was the collection itself that tracked the current position, you couldn't have several threads enumerating the same collection, or even nested enumerations such as this:

```
foreach (var x in collection)
{
    foreach (var y in collection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", x, y);
    }
}
```

By delegating the responsibility of tracking the current position to a different object (the enumerator), it makes each enumeration of the collection independent from the others

Comment: You have been skeeted by 6 seconds.

Answer (score 8):

A bit of a long answer, the two previous answers cover most of it, but I found some aspects I found interesting when looking up foreach in the `C#` language specification. Unless you are interested in that, stop reading.

Now over to the intering part, according to `C#` spec expansion of the following statements:

```
foreach (V v in x) embedded-statement
```

Gves you:

```
{`
 E e = ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator();
 try {
    while (e.MoveNext()) {
        V v = (V)(T)e.Current;
        embedded-statement
    }
}
 finally {
    … // Dispose e
 }
}
```

Having some kind of identity function which follows `x == ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator()` (it is it's own enumerator) and using @JonSkeet's loops produces something like this (removed try/catch for brevity):

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

while (list.MoveNext()) {
 int x = list.Current; // x is always 1
 while (list.MoveNext()) {
   int y = list.Current; // y becomes 2, then 3
   Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", x, y);
 }
}
```

Will print something along the lines of:

```
1 2
1 3
```

And then `list.MoveNext()` will return `false` forever. Which makes a very important point, if you look at this:

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

// loop
foreach (var x in list) Console.WriteLine(x); // Will print 1,2,3
// loop again
// Will never enter loop, since reset wasn't called and MoveNext() returns false
foreach (var y in list) Console.WriteLine(x); // Print nothing
```

So with the above in mind, and note that it is totally doable since the `foreach` statement looks for a `GetEnumerator()`-method before it checks whether or not the type implements `IEnumerable<T>`:

> Why was the above approach not followed and the problems I will face
>   if I follow it?

You cannot nest loops, nor can you use the `foreach` statement to access the same collection more than once without calling `Reset()` manually between them. Also what happens when we dispose of the enumerator after each `foreach`?

> How does presence of IEnumerator interface solves those problems?

All iterations are independent of each other, whether we are talking nesting, multiple threads etc, the enumeration is separate from the collection itself. You can think of it as a bit like [separations of concerns, or SoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), since the idea is to separate the traversal from the actual list itself and that the traversal under no circumstances should alter the state of the collection. IE a call to `MoveNext()` with your example would modify the collection.

Answer (score 3):

Others have already answered your question, but I want to add another little detail.

Let's decompile [System.Collection.Generics.List(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Its definition looks like this:

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

and its enumerator definition looks like this:

```
public struct Enumerator : IEnumerator<T>, IDisposable, IEnumerator
```

As you can see, **List** itself is a class, but its **Enumerator** is a struct, and this design [helps boost performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168311/why-bcl-collections-use-struct-enumerators-not-classes).
Lets assume that you do not have a separation between `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator`. In this situation you are forced to make **List** a struct, but [this is not a very good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil), so you cannot do that. Therefore, you are loosing a good opportunity to gain some performance boost.

With the separation between `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator` you can implement each interface as you like and use `struct` for enumerators.

Comment: How does Enumerator being a struct helps boost performance and what happens if it were a class?

Comment: @zizouraj: structs are passed by value, allocated on the stack and don't have to be collected by the GC (although that's actually an implementation detail, but an important one performance wise). Note that in 99% cases you **shouldn't use structs** (especially not mutable ones), and that BCL team allowed themselves this microoptimization just because this is a core collection intended to be used a lot.

Comment: @Groo: Using a struct to implement `IEnumerator<T>` won't improve performance in cases where code uses `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()`.  Both C# and VB.NET look to see if a collection has a method called `GetEnumerator` which returns something that has a `MoveNext` method and `Current` property; `List<T>` has such a method, separate from its implementation of `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator`. It's too bad VB.NET and C# require the method to be named `GetEnumerator`, since otherwise the ideal behavior would have been to have `GetEnumerator` return a class, but have the method used by...

Comment: `foreach` return a struct.  That ship has long since sailed, however.

Answer (score 2):

The iteration logic (foreach) is not bound to IEnumerables or IEnumerator. What you need foreach to work is a method called GetEnumerator in the class that returns an object of class that has MoveNext(), Reset() methods and the Current property. For example the following code works and it will create an endless loop.

In a design perspective the seperation is to ensure that the container(IEnumerable) does not keep any state during and after the completion of the iteration(foreach) operations.

```
    public class Iterator 
    {
        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {

        }

        public object Current { get; private set; }
    }

    public class Tester
    {
        public Iterator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new Iterator();
        }

        public static void Loop() 
        {
           Tester tester = new Tester();
           foreach (var v in tester)
           {
              Console.WriteLine(v);
           }

        }

    }
```