# Instantiation of List with Enumerator

Tags: c#, list, enumerator

I've seen this line in a code snipped and was wondering of the use of it

```
var item = new List<int>.Enumerator();
```

What does this do?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x854yt9s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Dr.Snail I stand corrected and I removed the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is something quite useless and wrong...

The first question should be what is the `List<T>.Enumerator`... It is a support class of `List<T>` that implements the `IEnumerator<T>` interface (the interface used for enumerating a collection, used for example by the `foreach`). [For performance reasons it is a `struct` instead of being a `class`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168311/why-do-bcl-collections-use-struct-enumerators-not-classes). Being a `struct` is has a predefined public parameterless constructor (the one you are using). It has even an `internal` constructor with one parameter (`List<T> list`) that sets some necessary internal fields (the most important is a reference to the `List<>` that created it). This constructor is used by `List<>.GetEnumerator()`.

Now, if you do what you wrote, you will create an "incomplete" `Enumerator`. The `item.Current` will "work" (returning a `default(T)`) but if you try to do a `item.MoveNext()` you'll get a `NullReferenceException`. If you want an `IEnumerator` for an "empty" collection, it would be better to do:

```
var item = Enumerable.Empty<int>().GetEnumerator();
```

For the reason why `List<T>.Enumerator` is `public` instead of being `private` or `internal`... It is a little more complex. `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable`, so it must have at least two methods with these signatures:

```
IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
```

and

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
```

but for performance reasons it implements them as explicit implementation (so hiding them), and implements a third method:

```
public Enumerator GetEnumerator()
```

that returns a `struct Enumerator`... now, thanks to how `foreach` works, this third public method will be the one used by `foreach`. Why this? Because a `struct` used through one of its interfaces (`IEnumerator<T>` or `IEnumerator` in this case) is boxed (something that slows it a little)... but if the `struct` is used directly (through its `public Enumerator GetEnumerator()`) method, there is no boxing and the performance is a little better... Microsoft programmers gave their 110% on `List<>` performances :-)

Answer (score 1):

I went to code to find out more , This is what i found [image]

so `var item = new List<int>.Enumerator();` return you instance of `Enumerable` structure , which is going to map to your list. As Enumerator is structure it will initialize its member with default value , in this case based on code it will initialize list to null. for detail you can see [code of list.](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs)

In this case there is no list instance exist , so if you access any method like this

```
var item = new List<int>.Enumerator();
item.Currnet or item.MovNext()
```

throws exception mostly or default int you have to tried that out.

In detail : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs

```
 public struct Enumerator : IEnumerator<T>, System.Collections.IEnumerator
        {
            private List<T> list;
            private int index;
            private int version;
            private T current;

            internal Enumerator(List<T> list) {
                this.list = list;
                index = 0;
                version = list._version;
                current = default(T);
            }

            public void Dispose() {
            }

            public bool MoveNext() {

                List<T> localList = list;

                if (version == localList._version && ((uint)index < (uint)localList._size)) 
                {                                                     
                    current = localList._items[index];                    
                    index++;
                    return true;
                }
                return MoveNextRare();
            }

            private bool MoveNextRare()
            {                
                if (version != list._version) {
                    ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion);
                }

                index = list._size + 1;
                current = default(T);
                return false;                
            }
```