# Can someone demystify the yield keyword?

Tags: c#, language-features, yield

I have seen the yield keyword being used quite a lot on Stack Overflow and blogs. I don't use [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query). Can someone explain the yield keyword?

I know that similar questions exist.
But none really explain what is its use in plain simple language.

Comment: Pretty much duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476/what-is-the-yield-keyword-used-for-in-c

Comment: okay this might be similar. But, answers here are different, much more aligned with this question and better(w.r.t this question) than those in that post.

Comment: May I ask a question at this point ? Whenever a type returns IEnumerable<> which means I can iterate it then right ? Because it has GetEnumerator() method right ? Thanks.

Comment: @Aaron: You can iterate a type that implements `IEnumerable<T>`, which (because it implements `IEnumerable<T>`) has a `GetEnumerator()` method.

Comment: If you "don't use LINQ" you should give it a go - you'll never look back!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

By far the best explanation of this (that I've seen) is Jon Skeet's book - and that chapter is free! Chapter 6, [C# in Depth](http://www.manning.com/skeet/). There is nothing I can add here that isn't covered.

Then buy the book; you will be a better C# programmer for it.

---

Q: Why didn't I write a longer answer here (paraphrased from comments); simple. As Eric Lippert observes ([here](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/24/iterator-blocks-part-seven-why-no-anonymous-iterators.aspx)), the `yield` construct (and the magic that goes behind it) is the **single most complex bit of code in the C# compiler**, and to try and describe it in a brief reply here is naïve at best. There are so many nuances to `yield` that IMO it is better to refer to a pre-existing (and fully qualified) resource.

Eric's blog now has 7 entries (and that is just the recent ones) discussing `yield`. I have a **vast** amount of respect for Eric, but his blog is probably more appropriate as a "further information" for people who *are* comfortable with the subject (`yield` in this case), as it typically describes a lot of the background *design* considerations. Best done in the context of a reasonable foundation.

(and yes, chapter 6 *does* download; I verified...)

Comment: So I'm confused: am I upvoting you or skeet here? :P

Comment: It doesn't matter - we're both maxed for the the day ;-p

Comment: @Alex - cheeky ;-p No - an independent recommendation.

Comment: +1 for the book; it's been awesome so far and I've barely had the chance to get into it

Comment: -1. Not to dismiss the book, but this doesn't come close to answering the question. The chapter 6 doesn't even load as we speak actually. Why not answer and then link to the book for additional information?

Comment: Indeed, that series of articles is explicitly about the *weird corner cases* of iterators that drove nonorthogonalities into the design, not about by-design "mainline" cases.

Comment: @AD has Manning Publication's server been StackOverflow'd?

Comment: Well, It's my first time to read this book and it's really awesome. Well, actually I am really understanding the meaning of Nirvana with this book. Thanks. (Nope, I am not advertising anything, if something is good, then it should be suggested. Period)

Comment: @Aaron - 2nd edition is in progress, according to Manning ;-p

Comment: Agree with @ADB. i came here hoping to find an answer, and instead there's not an answer.

Comment: @Ian I could **add** an explicit breakdown of an iterator block, if you really want...

Comment: No need, Brian's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330489/can-someone-demystify-the-yield-keyword/1330543#1330543) explained what `yield` is for. But what's an `iterator block`?

Comment: @Ian that is the C# code that gets translated by the compiler into an iterator implementation via a state machine

Comment: @Ian simply: a method using the `yield` keyword and processing is formally known as an *iterator block*.

Answer (score 31):

The `yield` keyword is used with methods that return `IEnumerable<T>` or `IEnumerator<T>` and it makes the compiler generate a class that implements the necessary plumbing for using the iterator. E.g.

```
public IEnumerator<int> SequenceOfOneToThree() {
    yield return 1;
    yield return 2;
    yield return 3;
}
```

Given the above the compiler will generate a class that implements `IEnumerator<int>`, `IEnumerable<int>` and `IDisposable` (actually it will also implement the non-generic versions of `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator`).

This allows you to call the method `SequenceOfOneToThree` in a `foreach` loop like this

```
foreach(var number in SequenceOfOneToThree) {
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

An iterator is a state machine, so each time `yield` is called the position in the method is recorded. If the iterator is moved to the next element, the method resumes right after this position. So the first iteration returns 1 and marks that position. The next iterator resumes right after one and thus returns 2 and so forth.

Needless to say you can generate the sequence in any way you like, so you don't have to hard code the numbers like I did. Also, if you want to break the loop you can use `yield break`.

Comment: In the 12 Stackoverflow, 2 msdn, and 3 web-sites tabs i have open: this is the one to explain *why* i would use yield. It certainly is a tricky concept, which sounds a lot like premature optimization.

Answer (score 18):

In an effort to demystify I'll avoid talking about iterators, since they could be part of the mystery themselves.

the yield return and yield break statements are most often used to provide "deferred evaluation" of the collection.

What this means is that when you get the value of a method that uses yield return, the collection of things you are trying to get don't exist together yet (it's essentially empty). As you loop through them (using foreach) it will execute the method at that time and get the next element in the enumeration.

Certain properties and methods will cause the entire enumeration to be evaluated at once (such as "Count").

Here's a quick example of the difference between returning a collection and returning yield:

```
string[] names = { "Joe", "Jim", "Sam", "Ed", "Sally" };

public IEnumerable<string> GetYieldEnumerable()
{
    foreach (var name in names)
        yield return name;
}

public IEnumerable<string> GetList()
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    foreach (var name in names)
        list.Add(name);

    return list;
}

// we're going to execute the GetYieldEnumerable() method
// but the foreach statement inside it isn't going to execute
var yieldNames = GetNamesEnumerable();

// now we're going to execute the GetList() method and
// the foreach method will execute
var listNames = GetList();

// now we want to look for a specific name in yieldNames.
// only the first two iterations of the foreach loop in the 
// GetYieldEnumeration() method will need to be called to find it.
if (yieldNames.Contains("Jim")
    Console.WriteLine("Found Jim and only had to loop twice!");

// now we'll look for a specific name in listNames.
// the entire names collection was already iterated over
// so we've already paid the initial cost of looping through that collection.
// now we're going to have to add two more loops to find it in the listNames
// collection.
if (listNames.Contains("Jim"))
    Console.WriteLine("Found Jim and had to loop 7 times! (5 for names and 2 for listNames)");
```

This can also be used if you need to get a reference to the Enumeration before the source data has values. For example if the names collection wasn't complete to start with:

```
string[] names = { "Joe", "Jim", "Sam", "Ed", "Sally" };

public IEnumerable<string> GetYieldEnumerable()
{
    foreach (var name in names)
        yield return name;
}

public IEnumerable<string> GetList()
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    foreach (var name in names)
        list.Add(name);

    return list;
}

var yieldNames = GetNamesEnumerable();

var listNames = GetList();

// now we'll change the source data by renaming "Jim" to "Jimbo"
names[1] = "Jimbo";

if (yieldNames.Contains("Jimbo")
    Console.WriteLine("Found Jimbo!");

// Because this enumeration was evaluated completely before we changed "Jim"
// to "Jimbo" it isn't going to be found
if (listNames.Contains("Jimbo"))
    // this can't be true
else
   Console.WriteLine("Couldn't find Jimbo, because he wasn't there when I was evaluated.");
```

Comment: Helped me demystify it a little bit more =)

Comment: Terrific explanation for a beginner to the concept

Answer (score 10):

The `yield` keyword is a convenient way to write an `IEnumerator`. For example:

```
public static IEnumerator<int> Range(int from, int to)
{
    for (int i = from; i < to; i++)
    {
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

is transformed by the C# compiler to something similiar to:

```
public static IEnumerator<int> Range(int from, int to)
{
    return new RangeEnumerator(from, to);
}

class RangeEnumerator : IEnumerator<int>
{
    private int from, to, current;

    public RangeEnumerator(int from, int to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.current = from;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        this.current++;
        return this.current < this.to;
    }

    public int Current
    {
        get
        {
            return this.current;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) documentation and the example. It is essentially an easy way to  create an iterator in C#.

```
public class List
{
    //using System.Collections;
    public static IEnumerable Power(int number, int exponent)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int result = 1;
        while (counter++ < exponent)
        {
            result = result * number;
            yield return result;
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        // Display powers of 2 up to the exponent 8:
        foreach (int i in Power(2, 8))
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That one is nice. Pretty obvious what yeild is used for.

Answer (score 4):

Eric White's [series on functional programming](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/pages/FP-Tutorial.aspx) it well worth the read in it's entirety, but the [entry on Yield](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/pages/The-Yield-Contextual-Keyword.aspx) is as clear an explanation as I've seen.

Answer (score 3):

[`yield`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) is not directly related to LINQ, but rather to [iterator blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx). The linked MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx) gives great detail on this language feature. See especially the [Using Iterators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zzykke.aspx) section. For deep details of iterator blocks, see Eric Lippert's recent blog [posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Iterators/default.aspx) on the feature. For the general concept, see the Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator) on iterators.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this to overcome a .NET shortcoming having to manually deep copy List.

I use this:

```
static public IEnumerable<SpotPlacement> CloneList(List<SpotPlacement> spotPlacements)
{
    foreach (SpotPlacement sp in spotPlacements)
    {
        yield return (SpotPlacement)sp.Clone();
    }
}
```

And at another place:

```
public object Clone()
{
    OrderItem newOrderItem = new OrderItem();
    ...
    newOrderItem._exactPlacements.AddRange(SpotPlacement.CloneList(_exactPlacements));
    ...
    return newOrderItem;
}
```

I tried to come up with oneliner that does this, but it's not possible, due to yield not working inside anonymous method blocks.

EDIT:

Better still, use a generic List cloner:

```
class Utility<T> where T : ICloneable
{
    static public IEnumerable<T> CloneList(List<T> tl)
    {
        foreach (T t in tl)
        {
            yield return (T)t.Clone();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me add to all of this. Yield is not a keyword.
It will only work if you use "yield return" other than that it will work like a normal variable.

It's uses to return iterator from a function. You can search further on that.
I recommend searching for "Returning Array vs Iterator"

Comment: Yield is a keyword of C#. It is an _unreserved contextual keyword_, but it is still a keyword.