# The wonders of the yield keyword

Tags: c#, enumeration, yield, yield-return

Ok, as I was poking around with building a custom enumerator, I had noticed this behavior that concerns the **yield**

Say you have something like this:

```
  public class EnumeratorExample 
  {

        public static IEnumerable<int> GetSource(int startPoint) 
        {
                int[] values = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
                Contract.Invariant(startPoint < values.Length);
                bool keepSearching = true;
                int index = startPoint;

                while(keepSearching) 
                {
                      yield return values[index];
                      //The mind reels here
                      index ++ 
                      keepSearching = index < values.Length;
                }
        }

  }
```

What makes it possible underneath the compiler's hood to execute the index ++ and the rest of the code in the while loop after you technically do a return from the function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler rewrites the code into a state machine. The single method you wrote is split up into different parts. Each time you call `MoveNext` (either implicity or explicitly) the state is advanced and the correct block of code is executed.

Suggested reading if you want to know more details:

- The implementation of iterators in C# and its consequences - Raymond Chen

  - [Part 1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080812-00/?p=21273)
  - [Part 2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080813-00/?p=21253)
  - [Part 3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080814-00/?p=21243)
- [Iterator block implementation details: auto-generated state machines](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx) - Jon Skeet
- [Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/iterators/)

Comment: Yes, ok, state machine, that's what I read. But what kinda code does it generate and whats that state machine is doing with it? Pseudo code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Max Malygin: The article I linked to http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx shows the code that is generated.

Comment: Also check Matt Greer's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455796/the-wonders-of-the-yield-keyword/4455832#4455832 He also found part 4 of the series.

Comment: Thanks for the shout-out. This link might be better, since it gives them in order: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/iterators/

Answer (score 4):

The compiler generates a state-machine on your behalf.

From the language specification:

> **10.14 Iterators**
>
> 10.14.4 Enumerator objects
>
> When a function member returning an
>   enumerator interface type is
>   implemented using an iterator block,
>   invoking the function member does not
>   immediately execute the code in the
>   iterator block. Instead, an enumerator
>   object is created and returned. This
>   object encapsulates the code specified
>   in the iterator block, and execution
>   of the code in the iterator block
>   occurs when the enumerator object’s
>   MoveNext method is invoked. An
>   enumerator object has the following
>   characteristics:
>
> • It implements
>   IEnumerator and IEnumerator, where
>   T is the yield type of the iterator.
>
> • It implements System.IDisposable.
>
> • It is initialized with a copy of the
>   argument values (if any) and instance
>   value passed to the function member.
>
> • It has four potential states,
>   before, running, suspended, and after,
>   and is initially in the before state.
>
> An enumerator object is typically an
>   instance of a compiler-generated
>   enumerator class that encapsulates the
>   code in the iterator block and
>   implements the enumerator interfaces,
>   but other methods of implementation
>   are possible. If an enumerator class
>   is generated by the compiler, that
>   class will be nested, directly or
>   indirectly, in the class containing
>   the function member, it will have
>   private accessibility, and it will
>   have a name reserved for compiler use
>   (§2.4.2).

To get an idea of this, here's how Reflector decompiles your class:

```
public class EnumeratorExample
{
    // Methods
    public static IEnumerable<int> GetSource(int startPoint)
    {
        return new <GetSource>d__0(-2) { <>3__startPoint = startPoint };
    }

    // Nested Types
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <GetSource>d__0 : IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable, IEnumerator<int>, IEnumerator, IDisposable
    {
        // Fields
        private int <>1__state;
        private int <>2__current;
        public int <>3__startPoint;
        private int <>l__initialThreadId;
        public int <index>5__3;
        public bool <keepSearching>5__2;
        public int[] <values>5__1;
        public int startPoint;

        // Methods
        [DebuggerHidden]
        public <GetSource>d__0(int <>1__state)
        {
            this.<>1__state = <>1__state;
            this.<>l__initialThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        }

        private bool MoveNext()
        {
            switch (this.<>1__state)
            {
                case 0:
                    this.<>1__state = -1;
                    this.<values>5__1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
                    this.<keepSearching>5__2 = true;
                    this.<index>5__3 = this.startPoint;
                    while (this.<keepSearching>5__2)
                    {
                        this.<>2__current = this.<values>5__1[this.<index>5__3];
                        this.<>1__state = 1;
                        return true;
                    Label_0073:
                        this.<>1__state = -1;
                        this.<index>5__3++;
                        this.<keepSearching>5__2 = this.<index>5__3 < this.<values>5__1.Length;
                    }
                    break;

                case 1:
                    goto Label_0073;
            }
            return false;
        }

        [DebuggerHidden]
        IEnumerator<int> IEnumerable<int>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            EnumeratorExample.<GetSource>d__0 d__;
            if ((Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId == this.<>l__initialThreadId) && (this.<>1__state == -2))
            {
                this.<>1__state = 0;
                d__ = this;
            }
            else
            {
                d__ = new EnumeratorExample.<GetSource>d__0(0);
            }
            d__.startPoint = this.<>3__startPoint;
            return d__;
        }

        [DebuggerHidden]
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Int32>.GetEnumerator();
        }

        [DebuggerHidden]
        void IEnumerator.Reset()
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
        }

        // Properties
        int IEnumerator<int>.Current
        {
            [DebuggerHidden]
            get
            {
                return this.<>2__current;
            }
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            [DebuggerHidden]
            get
            {
                return this.<>2__current;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yield is magic.

Well, not really.  The compiler generates a full class to generate the enumeration that you're doing.  It's basically sugar to make your life simpler.

Read [this](http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2008/06/09/behind-the-scenes-of-the-c-yield-keyword/) for an intro.

EDIT: Wrong this.  Link changed, check again if you have once.

Comment: @Max - Depending on when you clicked through on the link, it may be different now.  I originally posted the wrong one.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an excellent blog series (from Microsoft veteran Raymond Chen) that details how yield works:

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080812-00/?p=21273
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080813-00/?p=21253
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080814-00/?p=21243
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080815-00/?p=21223

Answer (score 2):

That's one of the most complex parts of the C# compiler. Best read the free sample chapter of Jon Skeet's **C# in Depth** (or better, get the book and read it :-)

> **[Implementing iterators the easy way](http://www.manning-source.com/books/skeet/Chapter6sample.pdf)**

For further explanations see Marc Gravell's answer here:

> **[Can someone demystify the yield keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330489/can-someone-demystify-the-yield-keyword)**