# Using yield in C#

Tags: c#, yield-return

I have a vague understanding of the `yield` keyword in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), but I haven't yet seen the need to use it in my code. This probably comes from a lack of understanding of it.

So, what are some typical good usages of `yield`?

Comment: There is a very good answer regarding the Yield keyword [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476/what-is-the-yield-keyword-used-for-in-c)

Comment: Try this first: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=yield+c%23, the first page of results has at least 5 questions which should help you.

Comment: Oh, thanks! A lot of useful stuff there!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476/what-is-the-yield-keyword-used-for-in-c

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`yield` just makes it very simple to implement an enumerator. So if you wanted write a method that returns an `IEnumerable<T>` it saves you having to create the enumerator class - you just `yield` one result at a time and the compiler takes care of the details under the covers.

One handy case is to write an "infinite enumerator" that the caller can call as many times as it needs to. Here's an example that generates an infinite series of Fibonacci numbers: http://chrisfulstow.com/fibonacci-numbers-iterator-with-csharp-yield-statements/ (well... *theoretically* infinite, but in practice limited to the size of UInt64).

Answer (score 4):

Yield implements the pattern of lazy loading. I suggest to consider its usefulness from this perspective.

For example. in the context of business software I'm working on, it could brings the advantage of lowering load on the database. You write code that pulls a variety of data from the database, but only that portion will be loaded which is really needed for a particular scenario. If a user doesn't go deeper in the UI, the respective data will not be loaded.

Comment: That was a really useful example that demonstrates that you have a long list that might not be used fully.

Answer (score 4):

Yield is used in enumerators. The C# compiler automatically pauses execution of your enumeration loop and returns the current value to the caller.

```
IEnumerable<int> GetIntegers(int max) {
    for(int i = 1; i <= max) {
         yield return i; // Return current value to the caller
    }
}
```

-- or (more clunky) --

```
IEnumerable<int> GetIntegers(int max) {
    int count = 0;
    while(true) {
         if(count >= max) yield break; // Terminate enumeration

         count++;
         yield return count; // Return current value to the caller
    }
}
```

More details on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0%28VS.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Also pretty good in testing and mocking when you just want to test an IEnumerable<> quickly, something like...

```
yield return somevalue;
yield return someothervalue;
yield return yetanotherone;
```