# Create an array or List of all dates between two dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I am generating multi-series graphs with the date along the X-Axis.

The problem is that not all of the series in the graph have the same dates in the date range.  Meaning that if I choose 1 Feb through 30 Apr that one series may have data that starts at 1 Feb but only goes through the end of March but another series may have data for the entire date range.

This skews the charts I need to create.  Go, given the date range taken at the begining of the query I'd like to generate a list of dates and populate the data to be graphed, padding those series with 0's for those dates that have no data.

Answer (score 463, accepted):

**LINQ:**

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + end.Subtract(start).Days)
          .Select(offset => start.AddDays(offset))
          .ToArray();
```

**For loop:**

```
var dates = new List<DateTime>();

for (var dt = start; dt <= end; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
{
   dates.Add(dt);
}
```

EDIT:
As for padding values with defaults in a time-series, you could enumerate all the dates in the full date-range, and pick the value for a date directly from the series if it exists, or the default otherwise. For example:

```
var paddedSeries = fullDates.ToDictionary(date => date, date => timeSeries.ContainsDate(date) 
                                               ? timeSeries[date] : defaultValue);
```

Comment: I follow the LINQ example until the `Select` statement. What exactly is happening there?

Comment: If you want a range that goes for 5 days, for example 4/9 - 4/13, the call to Enumerable.Range would create a collection {0,1,2,3,4}.  The select statement takes that collection and for each element, adds that value to the start date and returns the new date.  #4/9/2012#.AddDays(0) = 4/9/2012, #4/9/2012#.AddDays(1) = 4/10/2012, #4/9/2012#.AddDays(2) = 4/11/2012, and so on, thus generating the range of dates.

Comment: You should probably use `TotalDays` and not `Days`

Comment: @yellowblood: Why? Fractional days are not required.

Comment: @Matt Mitchell: I've reverted the edit you made where you claimed to be fixing a bug. Could you clarify what sort of bug you were attempting to fix?

Comment: My apologies, misread. Correct to retract the edit.

Comment: Condition to check the created date(based on offset) is less than or equal to end date is missing

Comment: how to use or call your 1st set of code @Ani

Comment: I really like this for-loop. It's not everyday you see a loop on `DateTime`.

Comment: while Linq is always nice, and often more legible than its looping counterpart, the for loop here is much more immediately legible ... thanks for including both!

Answer (score 44):

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDateRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    if (endDate < startDate)
        throw new ArgumentException("endDate must be greater than or equal to startDate");

    while (startDate <= endDate)
    {
        yield return startDate;
        startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to compare just the Date portion, modify the while condition:  
  while (startDate.Date <= endDate.Date).
Otherwise, you'll get a different range depending on how the DateTime value is constructed.

Comment: Since the loop should end when it equals to end date because we need dates between two start and end so end date should not include but the condition <= also return enddate.

Comment: I read the following explanations but still do not understand why you are using yield... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476/what-is-the-yield-keyword-used-for-in-c

Comment: @petrosmm this may be too late, as I believe you must have understood why, but they used yield so they could generate a list of `DateTime`  as demanded by the calling method instead of creating it at once (i.e. using an empty list of date and adding values to it, then return).

Answer (score 41):

I know this is an old post but try using an extension method:

```
    public static IEnumerable<DateTime> Range(this DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, (endDate - startDate).Days + 1).Select(d => startDate.AddDays(d));
    }
```

and use it like this

```
    var dates = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).Range(new DateTime(2000, 1, 31));
```

Feel free to choose your own dates, you don't have to restrict yourself to January 2000.

Answer (score 4):

Our resident maestro Jon Skeet has a great [Range Class](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/01/25/immutability-and-inheritance/) that can do this for DateTimes and other types.