# Group and Count in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, count

I have a table with Logs and I am counting the Logs per day as follows:

```
// Count logs by day
IList<DataModel> models = _context.Logs
  .Where(x => x.Created >= dateMinimum && x.Created <= dateMaximum)
  .GroupBy(x => new { Year = x.Created.Year, Month = x.Created.Month, Day = x.Created.Day })
  .Select(x => new { Year = x.Key.Year, Month = x.Key.Month, Day = x.Key.Day, Count = x.Count() })
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Select(x => new DataModel { Date = new DateTime(x.Year, x.Month, x.Day), LogsCount = x.Count })
  .ToList();

// Fill empty days with dates which contains all days in range
models.AddRange(dates.Where(x => !models.Any(y => y.Date == x.Date)).Select(x => new DataModel { Date = x, LogsCount = 0 }));
```

This is working if I want to count all logs by day independently of the type.

But I would like to count logs by day and type (Error, Warn, Info, ...).

I tried to add x.Type to group but at the end I get only 3 items.

At the moment my DataModel is the following:

```
public class DataModel
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public Int32 LogsCount { get; set; }
}
```

But maybe it should be something like:

```
public class DataModel
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public KeyValuePair<String, Int32> LogsCount { get; set; }
}
```

Where LogsCount has a string which holds the Type and Int32 which contains the count.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Might want to consider using [entity functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx) for grouping by date.

Example:

```
var results = query.GroupBy(r => new
{
    SentDate = System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(r.Launch.EmailDeliveredDate),
    EventSubTypeID = r.EmailEventSubtypeID
})
.Select(x => new
{
    x.Key.SentDate,
    x.Key.EventSubTypeID,
    NumResults = x.Count()
})
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like this?

```
IList<DataModel> models = Logs
  .Where(x => x.Created >= dateMinimum && x.Created <= dateMaximum)
  .GroupBy(x => new { Year = x.Created.Year, Month = x.Created.Month, Day = x.Created.Day, Type = x.Type })
  .Select(x => new { Year = x.Key.Year, Month = x.Key.Month, Day = x.Key.Day, Count = x.Count(), Type = x.Key.Type })
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Select(x => new DataModel { Date = new DateTime(x.Year, x.Month, x.Day), LogsCount = x.Count, Type = x.Type })
  .ToList()


public class DataModel
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public Int32 LogsCount { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was my first approach. And it works. But it gets confusing on how to fill the missing dates in the three types ... I am just not sure if that is the best approach ... How would you fill the empty dates in each type and add count = 0. Just like I do for total.

Comment: I'd probably do it in a `foreach` loop, across a list of dates generated as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3738781/298754).  For each date, if the value doesn't exist, add it.  I'm sure it can be done in LINQ, but it's not the way *I'd* do it.  I could try and come up with the LINQ form if you'd like.