# LINQ to Entities group by and Count()

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, count, group-by

I have the following LINQ-to-Entities query

```
from r in ctx.Rs
join p in ctx.Ps on r.RK equals p.RK
group r by r.QK into gr
select new { QK = (int)gr.Key, Num = gr.Count() }
```

that runs against this schema

```
Table P  Table R   Table Q
 PK*
 RK ----> RK*
 Text     QK ------> QK*
          Text       Text
```

and gives this message if there is any record in Q with no corresponding record in P: "The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."

The problem is the gr.Count() in the last line, but I cannot find a solution.  I have tried to test gr for null, but cannot find a way that works.

I have seen a number of solutions to a similar problem using Sum() instead of Count(), but I have not been able to adapt them to my problem.

I tried changing my query to look like the one in [Group and Count in Linq issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573785/group-and-count-in-linq-issue), but I just got a different message.

I also looked at [Group and Count in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012472/group-and-count-in-entity-framework) (and a number of others) but the problem is different.

Answer (score 18):

group Key can't be null

```
var results = ctx.Rs.Where(r => r.QK != null)
    .GroupBy(r => r.QK)
    .Select(gr => new { Key = (int)gr.Key, Count = gr.Count() }
    .ToList();
```

PS.

1. Mostly, You don't need 'JOIN' syntax in Entity Framework. see: [Loading Related Entities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx)
2. Writing descriptive-meaningful variable names would significantly improve Your codes and make it understandable. Readability does matter in real world production.

Comment: Well, actually it's less than perfect. It runs fine, but gives the wrong answer because it includes Rs that are not in P. When I try to fix that with a join, I get the same message.  Is there another way to exclude Rs that are not in P? Any other suggestions?

Comment: I did get your solution to work and return the correct result. The key is the '.Where(r => r.QK != null)' in the first line of your solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

I'm having trouble reading your format. But can you try:

```
from r in ctx.Rs
join p in ctx.Ps.DefaultIfEmpty() on r.RK equals p.RK
group r by r.QK into gr
select new { QK = (int)gr.Key, Num = gr.Count(x => x.RK != null) }
```

With `DefaultIfEmpty` and `x => x.RK != null` being the changes.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately, this still gives the same message.