# Create an array or List of all weeks between two dates and show on datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

try to show week numbers in datagridview as columns. Two date range to be selected, click on button and then show week numbers in datagrid as columns.

I am trying to create timeline chart by IDs and Week Numbers

This is what I am done so far by days, I want to select from dates and get weeks.

```
var daysCount = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, 1);

for (int i = 1; i <= daysCount; i++)
{
    grid1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn() 
    { 
        HeaderText = i.ToString(), 
        CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell() 
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. As a start, please read [FAQ] and [ask] couple of times..

Comment: This is by month and I want to do in weeks. var daysCount = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, 1);

            for (int i = 1; i <= daysCount; i++)
            {
                grid1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn() { HeaderText = i.ToString(), CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell() });
            }

Answer (score 0):

Check:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3738781/1043068

```
var start = new DateTime(2013, 9, 23);
var end = new DateTime(2013, 10, 5);

double daysBefore = (start - new DateTime(start.Year, 1, 1)).TotalDays;

int
    weekNumber = (int)Math.Ceiling(daysBefore / 7), // Start Day week number
    currentYear = start.Year; // used to check for a new year

for (var dt = start; dt <= end; dt = dt.AddDays(7))
{
    if (dt.Year > currentYear)
    {
        currentYear = dt.Year;
        weekNumber = 1;
    }

    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn
    {
        HeaderText = (weekNumber++).ToString(),
        CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
    });
}
```

Comment: This is giving me number of weeks, I want actual list of weeks. e.g. Start date = 2013-09-23 and End Date = 2013-10-05 in this date range week 40 and 41 should come.

Comment: [2013-09-23] in the week number 38 not 40, 
you need to calculate the offset.

Comment: Yes I have done it Just bit of for loop changes with one of weeknumber function. Thanks