# Adding missing dates to list between maximum and minimum date in LIST using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datetime, range

I'm trying to populate my list with missing dates where they have no sales...

I have defined a class like this:

```
   public class GroupedItem
    {
        public DateTime _Date { get; set; }
        public int Sales { get; set; }
    }
```

And now the list is populated like this:

```
var LineGraph = _groupedItems
                      .GroupBy(l => l._Date.Date)
                      .Select(cl => new GroupedItem
                      {
                           _Date = cl.Key,
                           Sales = cl.Sum(c=>c.Sales)
                      })
                      .OrderBy(x => x._Date)
                      .Where(t => t._Date <= DateTime.Now &&
                      t._Date >= DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(date_range)))
                      .ToList();
```

And the output that I get with this is like following:

```
11th December 6 sales
13th December 8 sales
18th December 12 sales
19th December 25 sales
```

This is rather okay, but I'd like to add the dates that are missing in between the first and last date so that I can have an output like this:

```
11th December 6 sales
12th December 0 sales
13th December 8 sales
14th December 0 sales 
15th December 0 sales
16th December 0 sales
17th December 0 sales
18th December 12 sales
21st December 25 sales
```

How can I achieve this with LINQ ?

Comment: My brain is having a hard time not wanting to just have a list of the dates in the date range that you left join on.

Comment: Really just left join? How can I do that in LINQ, I've never did it before..

Comment: I'm working on a solution using LinqPad currently, hold tight. It'll either be a left join or a union.

Comment: @EJC Okies thanks a lot ! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738748/create-an-array-or-list-of-all-dates-between-two-dates) has a way to generate a list of dates based on a range. I think we're going to have to union a list of dates to your groupedquery since it looks like to me your query results don't already contain rows for dates with 0 sales.

```
var LineGraph = _groupedItems.Union(Enumerable.Range(1, date_range)
          .Select(offset => new GroupedItem { _Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-(date_range)).AddDays(offset), Sales = 0} ))
                      .GroupBy(l => l._Date.Date)
                      .Select(cl => new GroupedItem
                      {
                           _Date = cl.Key,
                           Sales = cl.Sum(c=>c.Sales)
                      })
                      .Where(t => t._Date <= DateTime.Now &&
                      t._Date >= DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(date_range)))
                      .OrderBy(x => x._Date)
                      .ToList();
```

Corrected to include today and order by after the select.

Comment: It works in terms of adding missing day perfectly... Yeah this is the issue I haven't figured out yet, maybe it doesn't includes the first or last date given by the range?

Comment: Did you want to include today?

Comment: Yes I'd like to

Comment: P.S. I just tested the whole method on 30 days range, it shuffles the dates quite weirdly xD

Comment: It went from 1.12 to 22.12 , then it suddenly started from 22.11 for some reason lol

Comment: I moved the order by after the where which should help with the ordering. I've also corrected the query to include today.

Comment: Yeah thx a lot, btw. the dates are still in order like: 22.12, then it suddenly shifts to 23.11, 24.11 ,25.11,26.11,27.11,28.11,29.11,30.11 and thats where it ends

Comment: Data List Issue: It doesn't contain all of the dates like you want? 

Ordering: Hmm, is there another order by somwhere after this? When I `.Dump();` it in LinqPad it's in the right order.

Comment: Is your date range entering November month ? Mine date range is 22th of December to 23rd of November, they are aligned from 1-22 December correctly, and then after the 22.12 comes 23.11 (maybe we aren't checking of the month is bigger or smaller than  the current one ? )

P.S. This is the only order by

Comment: I've figured out that the problem isn't in the upgrade  u made, but actually on the view itself where i convert the date format

Comment: That's what I was getting at when I was asking about sorting after the initial query. Glad you found it.

Comment: Yeah ur upgrade works excellent and I've just accepted ur answer. Happy coding and happy new year mate :)

Comment: Thanks! Same to you!

Answer (score 3):

You can generate the list of dates and make a *left join* with `lineGraph` to generate the entire list:

```
var minDate = lineGraph.Min(g => g.Date);
var maxDate = lineGraph.Max(g => g.Date);
var range = GetDateRange(minDate, maxDate);

var result = from date in range
             from item in lineGraph.Where(g => g.Date.Date == date)
                                   .DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new GroupedItem
             {
                 Date = date,
                 Sales = item?.Sales ?? 0
             };
```

Use this method to generate the date range:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDateRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var date = startDate.Date;

    while (date <= endDate.Date)
    {
        yield return date;
        date = date.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can do something like this:

```
var min = _groupedItems.Min(g => g.Date);
var max = _groupedItems.Max(g => g.Date);
var range = GetDateRange(min, max).Select(d => new GroupedItem { Date = d, Sales = 0 });
```

And make your query against `range.Concat(_groupedItems)` instead of `_groupedItems`.

Comment: would this work if the date range goes 1 month into past ? Like for example: 22th December to 23th November ?

Comment: @User987: Using either the `left join` or `contact` solution, in both cases the range of dates goes from the earliest date to the latest date that appears in `_groupedItems` regardless of `range_date` value.