# Can't pickup all dates between two datetimepicker C# Win Forms

Tags: c#, ms-access

Have a problem with my soft... There is two datetimepickers in my app, i should make a list of dates between selected dates in my app. Also, i need to add them to Access datebase.

```
        DateTime start = new DateTime();
        start = dateTimePicker1.Value;
        DateTime end = new DateTime();
        end = dateTimePicker2.Value;


        Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + end.Subtract(start).Days)
        .Select(offset => start.AddDays(offset))
        .ToArray();

        var dates = new List<DateTime>();

        for (var dt = start; dt <= end; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
        {
            dates.Add(dt);
            richTextBox1.Text = dt.ToString();

        }
```

Thaks a lot!
UPDATED!

Comment: What have you tried yet? What is your problem with code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738748/create-an-array-or-list-of-all-dates-between-two-dates will get you the dates between two dates.

Comment: Did you read the link I provided?

Comment: @mjwills Yes, sir. But unfortunately couldn't test it yet. I will answer you in a day if it works

Comment: @mjwills, it didn't work

Comment: @mjwills, updated the code

Comment: Define 'it didn't work'. What did you expect? How did it act instead?

Comment: Also remove the Enumerable.Range code - it doesn't do anything useful unless you assign it to a variable (which you aren't doing).

Comment: @mjwills, it didn't work again. Richtextbox shows only the last date.
P.S. It's a hotel programm, i need to select all dates between arrival and departure day (it is necessary for looking up who is at hotel today).

Comment: @mjwills №1! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code to:

```
    DateTime start = new DateTime();
    start = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    DateTime end = new DateTime();
    end = dateTimePicker2.Value;

    var dates = new List<DateTime>();
    richTextBox1.Text = "";
    for (var dt = start; dt <= end; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
    {
        dates.Add(dt);
        richTextBox1.Text += dt.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mjwills! 
And one more, i swear, last question :D 
This code also adds time, is it possible to add just date, without time?