# How To asp.net MVC Two dates between All Dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two date example
12.1.2019
12.2.2019

```
 public class DatelistController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet]

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

       DateTime start = new DateTime(2012, 2, 1);
        DateTime end = new DateTime(2012, 3, 1); ;
        var dates = new List<DateTime>();

        for (var dt = start; dt <= end; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
        {
            dates.Add(dt);
        }
        Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + end.Subtract(start).Days)
         .Select(offset => start.AddDays(offset))
        .ToArray();
        ViewData["AllDate"] = new SelectList(dates);
        return View();
    }
```

Index

```
> @foreach (var item in ViewData["AllDate"] as List<DateTime>)
{
    <tr> 
    <td style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:12px;">@item</td>
        </tr>
        }
```

I can't Index page there are no structures that I built.

What i want to do it;

Select Start Date and End Date is two date between get All Date's
then later
I will put the value on the days obtained using the check box

I would be happy if you help Thank you!

Comment: Hi Avni sorry I can't really understand your question.

Comment: Hi I 
for my english sorry I have two date between get all date example; (22-02-2020)-(25.02.2020) output:(23.02-2020),(24.02-2020),(25.02-2020)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Comparing two `Day` will give you the wrong value. For example, You are comparing 11 of 11 Jan and 11 February and it will give you 0, but it is not.

Do like this.

```
DateTime start;
DateTime end;
var dates = new List<DateTime>();

for (var dt = start; dt <= end; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
{
    dates.Add(dt);
}
```

You can also use LINQ as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3738781/6527049).

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + end.Subtract(start).Days)
          .Select(offset => start.AddDays(offset))
          .ToArray();
```

view error=`System.NullReferenceException:  (... as System.Collections.Generic.List<System.DateTime>) returned null.`
Thank you

Comment: I very thank you;
how can i send view these values ​​now, I cant return dates how do it?

Comment: like this `foreach (var item in ViewData["Data"] as List<DateTime>)  
                {  
                    <tr>  
                        <td style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:12px;">@item</td>  
 
                    </tr>  
                } `

Comment: I cant sorry I error:System.NullReferenceException: 'Nesne başvurusu bir nesnenin örneğine ayarlanmadı.'

(... as System.Collections.Generic.List<System.DateTime>) returned null.

Comment: Are you setting value of ViewData?

Comment: DateTime start = new DateTime(2012, 2, 1);
            DateTime end = new DateTime(2012, 3, 1); ;
            var dates = new List<DateTime>();

            for (var dt = start; dt <= end; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
            {
                dates.Add(dt);
            }
            Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + end.Subtract(start).Days)
             .Select(offset => start.AddDays(offset))
            .ToArray();
            ViewData["AllDate"] = new SelectList(dates);

Comment: view code======>@foreach (var item in ViewData["Data"] as List<DateTime>)
{
    <tr> 
    <td style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:12px;">@item</td>
        </tr>
        }

Comment: It should be ViewData["AllDate"]  in the view. Because you are using it in controller.

Comment: I very very Thank you If I puzzling sorry