# When writing an enumerable, what does yield return var?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the yield keyword used for in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476/what-is-the-yield-keyword-used-for-in-c)

Say I have code that looks like:

(steam is a filestream)

```
using(BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(stream))
{
  foreach(byte[] b in BreakBytes(objectOfBytes))
  {
    writer.Write(b);
  }
}
```

So for BreakBytes to work, it has to do something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<byte[]> BreakBytes(byte[] b)
{
  ..
  while(..) {

     yield return some_buffer;

  }
  ..
}
```

What exactly is yield doing?  Does it keep track of where it was position wise?

I believe it is return to the calling foreach loop, but continues to the next iteration when called again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, the code in the method is re-written as a state machine that does as you suspect: it keeps track of where it is in the loop, returns to the caller, and continues where it left off.

Answer (score 1):

`yield` is really special in C# as it doesn't follow normal flow of control.

When iterating the returned `IEnumerable`, the `BreakBytes` function will be called and run until it has yielded a value. Control will then be passed back to the `foreach` loop. When the loop steps to the next item, `BreakBytes` is resumed and run until it hits another `yield`.

This somewhat odd construct gives the benefit that if only part of the `IEnumerable` is enumerated, only that part needs to be generated.

Answer (score 0):

Jon Skeet can tell you all about them: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx

Yes. It keeps track of its internal state.

Answer (score 0):

The yield return statement is the point where an iterator gives back an answer to the caller which is almost always a foreach loop implicity using the GetEnumerator() and MoveNext() methods of a collection that implements the IEnumerable and IEnumerator interfaces.

It does indeed keep it's state. The code inside of an iterator block like that can be thought to temporarily halt after the yield return statement until the next time the MoveNext() method is called when it will pick right back up where it left off until it hits another yield return.

For a much more in-depth explanation I highly recommend the book [C# in Depth, Second Edition](http://www.manning.com/skeet2).