# Yield can't understand the functionality

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

First, of all, I already search about this but i still can't I understand when to use yield.

For example I have the below code:

```
string[] days = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thr", "Fri", "Sat" };

public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < days.Length; i++)
    {
        yield return days[i];
    }
}
```

What would be the difference between the above code and below code?

```
string[] days = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thr", "Fri", "Sat" };

public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < days.Length; i++)
    {
        return days[i];
    }
}
```

Can you please tell me when to use yield?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is yield return in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407162/what-is-yield-return-in-c)

Comment: which is a possible duplicate of [What is the yield keyword used for in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476/what-is-the-yield-keyword-used-for-in-c) :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `return` method doesn't remember where you are in your array. It will return Sunday every single time you use it, simply because it starts that loop from zero every time.

Using `yield` is more (at least conceptually) "I'll return this value but, next time you call me, I'm going to pick up where I left off (inside the loop)".

A similar thing can be done in C with the use of static variables to remember where you are:

```
char *nextDay () {
    static char *days[] = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thr", "Fri", "Sat" };
    static int nextDay = -1;
    nextDay = (nextDay + 1) % (sizeof (days) / sizeof (*days));
    return days[nextDay];
}
```

The fact that the `nextDay` variable is maintained across invocations of the function means that it can be used to cycle through the array.

Comment: Hi in the code below 

string[] days = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thr", "Fri", "Sat" };

public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < days.Length; i++)
    {
        yield return days[i];
    }
}

When I first call it, it will return "sun", and in second time it will return "Mon"? Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: @pagodnautak, yes, any bugs notwithstanding (it's a little hard to read code in the comments box), that is the expected functionality.

Answer (score 4):

Certain constructs in C# will cause the compiler to turn the code into something very different.  The `yield return` statement causes such a transformation.  What looks like a function which performs a `yield return` is actually compiled into a class; many of the local variables in the function get transformed into class fields.  The class itself will typically implement `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>`.  The first time `MoveNext` is called, the class code will run the portion of the function up to the first `yield return`, and keep track of which `yield return` it hit.  The next time it's called, it will start execution there and run until the next `yield return` is called.  If there are any `Try/Finally` blocks, the portion of the code in the `Finally` block will get executed in response to `IDisposable.Dispose`.

The net effect is that the code the C# compiler produces for an iterator will look almost nothing like the code the programmer wrote.  The reason it seems like `yield return` does the impossible is that its behavior would be impossible for anything even remotely resembling a method call, but the compiler turns any function which contains a `yield return` into a class whose behavior doesn't even remotely resemble a method call.

Answer (score 0):

Yield interacts with foreach-loops and for loops. It allows each iteration in a foreach-loop or for loop be generated only when needed. In this way it can improve performance.

Complete explaination of yield and its benefits can be found here:

http://www.ytechie.com/2009/02/using-c-yield-for-readability-and-performance.html

Comment: It would be more accurate to say `yield` interacts with consumers of `IEnumerable`, of which, a `foreach` loop is but a common example.  Yield also works perfectly fine if you invoke `.GetEnumerator` yourself and traverse it manually.