# Linq - How to use a variable of type List<Entity> in Where clause

Tags: linq, entity-framework, t-sql

I am writing a filter for a displayed grid, so the only items displayed are those that have the same location id as the person logged in.  I have the linq query working to get the logged in users location(s) (yes a user can have multiple locations) and now I am trying to write what

I have a variable that is sometimes a list, sometimes a single value, but never null (it's a list of location codes).  I have tried a couple different ways, but both are throwing errors.

```
      public List<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        var UserLoc = repo.GetUserLocations();

        foreach (var item in UserLoc)
        {
            var query = (from p in db.Person
                              join t in db.TrespassedLocation on p.PersonId equals t.PersonId 
                              where t.SiteCode == item.LocationCode
                              select p).ToList();
            return query;
        }
        // Don't know what to return here?
    }
```

The above looks like it will work, if I can figure out what to return outside the foreach.

I also tried:

```
    public List<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        var UserLoc = repo.GetUserLocations();

        var query = (from p in db.Person
                           join t in db.TrespassedLocation on p.PersonId equals t.PersonId 
                           where t.SiteCode equals UserLoc
                           select p).ToList();
        return query;
    }
```

but this gives a "cant convert string to bool" error on the where clause.  I have tried using '==' instead of 'equals', same error.

Lastly I tried 'contains' like so:

```
where t.SiteCode.Contains(UserLoc)
```

but that gives an error 'besting matching overload has invalid arguments' probably because it wants a string, not a List.

==== EDIT ====

Based of the link provided, I came up with this:

```
    public List<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        var UserLoc = GetUserLocations();

        var query = db.Person
                                .Join(db.TrespassedLocation,
                                            p => p.PersonId,
                                            t => t.PersonId,
                                            (p, t) => new { p, t })
                                .Where(t.SiteCode.equals(UserLoc));
    }
```

but I still get errors in the where clause ('t' does not exist and if try Contains instead of equals it complains of invalid arguments.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476/what-is-the-yield-keyword-used-for-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a list of objects and you want to see if an particular object is in that list, then you do:

```
myList.Contains(myObject);
```

You're looking to see if your list contains your object.  All your samples above seem to have this backwards.

Going back to your original sample, try this:

```
public List<Person> GetPeople()
{
  // Get the list of codes that the user belongs to
  var userLocationCodes = repo.GetUserLocations().Select(i => i.LocationCode);

  // Do one query to see if the location is in your list of location codes
  var query = (from p in db.Person
    join t in db.TrespassedLocation on p.PersonId equals t.PersonId
    where userLocationCodes.Contains(t.SiteCode)
    select p);
  return query.ToList();
}
```

However, some entity framework providers don't like `.Contains` on a local list.

If that's the case, then iterate over your local list like you were originally doing and add the results of each iteration's query into a master result set.

```
public List<Person> GetPeople()
{
  var UserLoc = repo.GetUserLocations();

  // This is what you return
  var results = new List<Person>(); 

  foreach (var item in UserLoc)
  {
    var query = (from p in db.Person
      join t in db.TrespassedLocation on p.PersonId equals t.PersonId
      where t.SiteCode == item.LocationCode
      select p).ToList();

    // Add this query to your master results
    results.AddRange(query);
  }
  return results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the peice I was missing was: var userLocationCodes = repo.GetUserLocations().Select(i => i.LocationCode); .  I didn't know I could do that.  I had flipped the contains around because it seemed to make more sense, anyway, you nailed it, thanks.