# Understanding YIELD keyword in c#

Tags: c#, yield-keyword

I came across these two code snippets while reading about IEnumerable interfaces. I would like to understand the exact difference between them in simple terms.

Snippet 1 : without yield,

```
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        // Return the array object's IEnumerator.
        return carArray.GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Snippet 2:with yield,

```
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (Car c in carArray)
        {
            yield return c;
        }
    }
```

Both the snippets do the same work, So whats so specific in using YIELD over here?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476/what-is-the-yield-keyword-used-for-in-c

Comment: In this specific case, there is probably not much gain, if carArray is really what it sounds, an `array` of `car` elements.

Answer (score 1):

yield return turns your stateful sequential code into an iterator.

Instead of having a separate class to manage the iterator position, like in the first example, you can iterate in code and "return" each value as you visit it. This is not a conventional return, it's a yield which is more of a context switch to the code calling you. The next iteration will resume you.

Comment: Thanks, added some details. Confession: I don't know c# but I really want to start using it for these features.

Answer (score 1):

The essence about `yield` is that it deferres actual execution to the time, when the value is really queried. In other words, a particular value is evaluated not at the time you ask for the **enumerator**, but at the time when the **value** is retrieved (lazy evaluation).

This has a number of implications:

- there is no need for (potentially huge) resource allocation to build the collection upfront
- when the enumeration terminates prematurely, values that are never queried must not be returned

Answer (score 0):

Ah, but there is a difference! `yield return` is a bit of syntactic sugar that yields control back to the calling function. It provides optimization opportunities so that if you know you are looking for a certain value in a collection, you don't have to return the whole collection to the caller, you can short-circuit the enumeration once you get what you need.

So how does it do it? `yield return` gets turned into a switch statement, which is described here: http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2008/06/09/behind-the-scenes-of-the-c-yield-keyword/

There is a really good video that also explains it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Or9g8LOhXhg