# Why is my foreach loop looping just once even though there are 3 items?

Tags: c#, .net

Below is a sample code.  My loop is only looping once even though there are three items in it. `items[0].Duration` is only returning the top item added.  It is not looping through the collection.

Any ideas?

```
public class DurationModel
{
    public string Duration { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<List<DurationModel>> GetDurationItems()
    {
        List<DurationModel> durationItems = new List<DurationModel>();

        durationItems.Add(new DurationModel()
        {
            Duration = "1 Day"
        });

        durationItems.Add(new DurationModel()
        {
            Duration = "1 Week"
        });

        durationItems.Add(new DurationModel()
        {
            Duration = "1 Month"
        });

        yield return durationItems;
    }
}

public class MyForm
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _durationItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    private IEnumerable<List<DurationModel>> _durationModel = new DurationModel().GetDurationItems();

    public MyForm()
    {
        GetData();
    }

    private void GetData()
    {
        foreach (var items  in _durationModel)
        {
            _durationItems.Add(items[0].Duration);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: The "common idiom" for using `yield return` from *an existing collection*: `foreach (var item in durationItems) yield return item;` (ie. for each item, yield it separately.) Of course, in this case yield-return can normally be avoided..

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, but it may be helpful to have a look at [this question and top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476/what-is-the-yield-keyword-used-for-in-c).

Comment: tl;dr: - Your `GetDurationItems` returns an `IEnumerable` that contains a single item - and that item is a list that contains three instances of `DurationModel`.

Answer (score 10):

With `yield return durationItems;` you are returning just one single item of type `List<DurationModel>`.  The list implements `IEnumerable<DurationModel>` or, in other words, **is an** `IEnumerable<DurationModel>`. Therefore, the return type must be `IEnumerable<DurationModel>` and not `IEnumerable<List<DurationModel>>`, which would be suited to return an enumeration of lists of `DurationModels`.

Change the method to

```
public IEnumerable<DurationModel> GetDurationItems()
{
    yield return new DurationModel { Duration = "1 Day" };
    yield return new DurationModel { Duration = "1 Week" };
    yield return new DurationModel { Duration = "1 Month" };
}
```

One item is returned per `yield return`. Alternatively, you could write

```
public IEnumerable<DurationModel> GetDurationItems()
{
    // This works because arrays implement IEnumerable<T>.
    return new DurationModel[] {
        new DurationModel { Duration = "1 Day" },
        new DurationModel { Duration = "1 Week" },
        new DurationModel { Duration = "1 Month" }
    };
}
```

You could use a `List<DurationModel>` as well.

Note that `yield return` makes the method pause, remember its state and return. When `foreach` requests the next item, the method resumes after the last `yield return`. (See also [Behind the scenes of the C# yield keyword](https://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2008/06/09/behind-the-scenes-of-the-c-yield-keyword/) by Lars Corneliussen)

With the first method, the items are created as they are used in the loop. With the second one they are all created when the loop starts.

`yield return` allows you to generate enumerations algorithmically, without storing the items in a collection

```
public IEnumerable<int> ThousandSquares()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
        yield return i * i;
    }
}

public void PrintSquares()
{
    foreach (int n in ThousandSquares()) {
        Console.WriteLine(n);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `yield return durationItems;` instead of `return durationItems;`.
You should add `_durationModel = new DurationModel().GetDurationItems();` in the constructor and after that call getData