# How the keyword yield remember which instruction is the next to execute and the stack frame state at that very moment when the control was given back?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, yield, stack-frame

I learned that when the control of a thread is given back from the function currently executing to its caller, its stack frame will be destroyed in the assembly, but it seems this doesn't hold true for the C# keyword `yield`.

Comment: I don't know enough to write an authoritative answer, but my understanding is that `yield` creates an anonymous class (the enumerator that is being returned) that can then hold all the necessary information to perform the deferred execution.

Comment: @dymanoid I think this question is more asking how `yield` is implemented, rather than it's usage

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, there are answers in that question which explain pretty much.

Comment: Since the linked answer doesn't have any SharpLab links to play with, [here's one](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAFgNwFgBQUDMCBMcAwnAN5ZyUJ5I4A8AlgHYAuAfHALIAUAlGRSpCkiBAHY4iDJiHDEoqBPzShAXyyqgA===)

Comment: @dymanoid This one comes close... https://stackoverflow.com/a/44801657/1783619 but they aren't the same question, even if one of the answers sort of answers this one. We can agree to disagree though

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Check out this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39507/1086121 and this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39482/1086121

Comment: googling led me to this : https://csharpindepth.com/articles/IteratorBlockImplementation

I don't know the date of this post, I guess the core principles are still true.

Comment: @canton7 Those would be good answers on this question (though the 1st is nearly link-only and the second very short). Still disagree it makes this one a dupe :)

Comment: @LeGEC: Yup, while some of the implementation details may have changed, the core ideas haven't.