# How to make new IEnumerable collection and return it?

Tags: c#, delegates, ienumerable

I need to pass an `IEnumerable` and a delegate to my method, and then filter it and return an `IEnumerable` collection with numbers that pass filter.

```
Func<int, bool> filter = x => x % 3 == 0;


public static IEnumerable<int> Filter(IEnumerable<int> numbers, Func<int, bool> filter)
{
    foreach (int number in numbers) 
    {
        if (filter.Invoke(number)) 
        {
            // add number to collection
        }
    }

    // return collection
}
```

I have tried creating a new collection like this:

```
IEnumerable<int> result = new IEnumerable<int>();
```

But it is not possible since `IEnumerable` is an abstract class.

How should I create and return this collection? I know that there is a lot of easy ways to do this, but can't find any.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the yield keyword used for in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476/what-is-the-yield-keyword-used-for-in-c)

Comment: Something like `numbers.Where(filter)`? You might not even need that method, `Enumerable.Where()` does that (and some more) for you.

Comment: I need a method because my task says so. But that's it, I knew there is an easy way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: You cannot instantiate `IEnumerable<T>` because it is an interface. If you use `List<T>` (which implements `IEnumerable<T>`) you'll be able to add items to it and then return that.

Comment: I know it is possible, but what if I pass Array to the method, and want array to be returned?

Comment: *But it is not possible since IEnumerable is an abstract class.* - no, actually - `IEnumerable` is an **interface** - not an abstract class !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @somebody pointed out, the right way to do this is to use `yield return`:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Filter(IEnumerable<int> numbers, Func<int, bool> filter) {
    foreach (int number in numbers) {
        if (filter.Invoke(number)) {
            yield return number;
        }
    }
}
```

When your returned collection (your returned `IEnumerable<int>`) is enumerated (via a `foreach` or a call to something like `ToList`), then you code will be called for the first item.  When you get to the `yield return`, the first number will be returned.  When the second pass (and subsequent passes) through the iteration occurs, the code will continue to execute on the line following the `yield return`.

For what it's worth, your code is pretty much exactly what LINQ's `Where` extension method does for `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: So what is better to use here then? And is there any difference?

Comment: Use `Where`.  Code you don't need to write or maintain is much cheaper (and, given that it comes with the Framework, much less likely to have a bug)