# The operand of yield return in c#

Tags: c#, ienumerable, yield-return

I had started learning iterator methods and implementation of IEnumerators in c#. I got confused at a point regarding the yield return statement.

Suppose, I create an iterator method 'Iterator()' and I have a collection 'myCollection' containing items of type 'TCustom'. myCollection is a collection type that implements 'IEnumerable' but, type 'TCustom' does not implement it.

```
IEnumerable Iterator()
{ 
  foreach(TCustom item in myCollection)
   {
     yield return item;
   }
}

class RandomCollection : IEnumerable{....}
class TCustom {....}
RandomCollection myCollection = new RandomCollection();
```

so the yield statement is returning 'item' object of type 'TCustom' from 'myCollection'. If 'TCustom' is a custom type created from my source code, does it have to implement IEnumerable interface? And if type 'TCustom' does not implement 'IEnumerable' interface, can it be a return type of yield return statement?
(yield return item;)

Comment: `yield return` produced the individual items in the collection, so T does not have to (and usually does not) implement IEnumerable.

Comment: FYI a single T is usually a placeholder for a Type in generics, not a specific class. It confused me at first 

Comment: @KlausGütter could you please elaborate on why individual items need not implement IEnumerable? And isn't there any specific operand type for 'yield' ?

Comment: It depends on the type of the collection. If it is `IEnumerable<int>`, you have to supply an `int`. If simply `IEnumerable`, it can be any `object`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the yield keyword used for in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476/what-is-the-yield-keyword-used-for-in-c) It is completely transformed into a separate class, which implements `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @Charlieface actually that thread does not clarify the return type of the yield statement, especially the confusion I encountered

Comment: @KlausGütter thank you for clarifying it. Additional question Ithat came to my mind, that the Object class does not implement IEnumerable, so how any object type in 'yield return object' also serves for IEnumerator?

Comment: Again: what you return in yield return is not the collection, it is an individual element. Only all of the encountered yield return's together form the final collection.

Comment: Once you understand how the state machine works, it should be pretty obvious what is being returned: the overall function outputs an `IEnumerable` but each `yield` statement only outputs one value being enumerated

Answer (score 1):

[IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) is an interface that defines one method **GetEnumerator** which returns an **[IEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx)** interface, this in turn allows readonly access to a collection. A collection that implements IEnumerable can be used with a foreach statement.

Definition

```
IEnumerable 

public IEnumerator GetEnumerator();

IEnumerator

public object Current;
public void Reset();
public bool MoveNext();
```

[example code from codebetter.com](http://codebetter.com/blogs/david.hayden/archive/2005/03/08/59419.aspx)

An `IEnumerator` is a thing that can enumerate: it has the `Current` property and the `MoveNext` and `Reset` methods (which in .NET code you probably won't call explicitly, though you could).

An `IEnumerable` is a thing that can be enumerated...which simply means that it has a GetEnumerator method that returns an `IEnumerator`.

Which do you use?  The only reason to use `IEnumerator` is if you have something that has a nonstandard way of enumerating (that is, of returning its various elements one-by-one), and you need to define how that works.  You'd create a new class implementing `IEnumerator`.  But you'd still need to return that `IEnumerator` in an `IEnumerable` class.

For a look at what an enumerator (implementing `IEnumerator<T>`) looks like, see any `Enumerator<T>` class, such as the ones contained in `List<T>`, `Queue<T>,` or `Stack<T>`.  For a look at a class implementing `IEnumerable`, see any standard collection class.